# Reparing the \jobname for use in titlehead

Tags: titles, jobname

If I name a LaTeX file `hw1`, I want to print `Homework 1`. How can I do this?

I can print the string `hw1` directly using `\jobname`, but I don't want spaces in my file name or have to type that out each time I make a new file.

Comment: Please provide a little more detail on how you use `\jobname` in your title? For example, why don't you just type `Homework 1` rather than referring to `\jobname`?

Answer (score 8):

Let's make this more general. I assume you have files named

```
<string><number>.tex
```

where `<string>` are arbitrary alphabetic characters and `<number>` is made of digits. For instance,

```
hw01.tex ... hw10.tex
```

for homeworks or

```
lect01.tex ... lect21.tex
```

for lectures. The structure of the `hw` file might be

```
\input{hw-common}

\begin{document}
\title{Homework \NUMBER}
\author{Georg Raba}
\date{}

\maketitle

Solve the following exercises

...

\end{document}
```

where `hw-common.tex` will contain the `\documentclass` line and other common settings for the homework files. One of the tasks of `hw-common` should be to define `\NUMBER` based on the file name. But you want to reuse the code and so make it independent of the actual `<string>` in the file name, so you can use the same code for `lect-common.tex`.

How can we do? The `l3regex` package in the LaTeX3 bundle comes, as usual, to the rescue.

In `hw-common.tex` you'll have

```
\usepackage{expl3,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Save a copy of \jobname
\tl_set_eq:NN \NUMBER \c_job_name_tl
\regex_replace_once:nnN { [A-Za-z0]* } { } \NUMBER
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

In this way, if the file is `hw01.tex`, `\NUMBER` will print 1, stripping the leading zero. The regular expression matches all initial alphabetic characters and zeroes and replaces them with nothing.

### Note

As of September 2015 the code should become

```
\usepackage{expl3,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Save a copy of \jobname
\tl_set:NV \NUMBER \c_sys_jobname_str
\regex_replace_once:nnN { [A-Za-z0]* } { } \NUMBER
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: But can you do it without LaTeX3 packages?

Comment: @Zack Doing it with this generality is really hard. One could think to look for digits, instead of letters, since those are the important things, and, upon finding one, stopping the search and extracting the number. With regular expressions the file name structure can be almost arbitrary.

Answer (score 6):

`\jobname` is like `\string`: it expands to a sequence of [category code 12](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16412/514) characters, even if the characters in question would not normally have catcode 12 (except spaces, which continue to be catcode 10).  You can use delimited arguments to extract a piece of the sequence and do something with it; the easiest "something" is to save them in a macro.  For instance, suppose you know that your `\jobname` will always have the form `XXXXwYYYY` where the YYYY is the piece you want, you could do this:

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\w=12
\def\extracthnum#1w#2\relax{#2}%
\xdef\hnum{\expandafter\extracthnum\jobname\relax}%
\endgroup
%
% ...
%
\title{Homework \hnum}
```

That probably deserves a little unpacking.

```
\begingroup\catcode`\w=12
```

Begin a group (you pretty much always want to wrap catcode changes in a group) and change the category code of `w` to 12 so that it will match the `w` in the expansion of `\jobname`.  Note that this means we cannot use `w` in macro names until we revert it to its normal catcode.  (There are ways to get around this if you really have to, but let's not get into that.)

```
\def\extracthnum#1w#2\relax{#2}%
```

Define `\extracthnum` as a macro taking two *delimited* arguments.  Unlike normal macros, this one's first argument will be all the input characters up to but not including the first catcode-12 `w` (that isn't inside a brace group), and the second argument will be all the characters *after* the `w` until the first occurrence of `\relax`.  (We use a control sequence to delimit the second argument because it cannot possibly occur in the expansion of `\jobname`.  It will be consumed and discarded; I used `\relax` because this is traditional, but it could be any control sequence. It doesn't even need to have a definition.)  It expands to its second argument.

```
\xdef\hnum{\expandafter\extracthnum\jobname\relax}%
```

This line is processed in an unusual order, because of the `\xdef` and the `\expandafter`.  `\jobname` is expanded *first*, then `\extracthnum ... \relax` acts upon what `\jobname` expands to, and only then does the macro definition happen.  Since by assumption `\jobname` has the form `XXXXwYYYY`, `\hnum` will be defined as `YYYY`.  The other special effect of `\xdef` is to make the definition *globally*, i.e. it will survive the `\endgroup` that's coming up next.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\def` on the command line to specify the value, and use that in your code.

```
pdflatex "\def\Title{Homework 1}\input{hw1}"
```

Your `hw1` file would use `\providecommand` to specify `\Title` if it was not specified on the command line. Now you can use `\Title` anywhere within the document:

```
%\def\Title{Homework 1} -- This is defined on the command line
\documentclass{article}
\providecommand*{\Title}{\jobname}

\begin{document}
Title is \Title
\end{document}
```