# \renewcommand with \caption*

Tags: macros, captions, starred-version

I'd like to redefine `\caption*` as

```
\renewcommand{\caption*}[1]{\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}\caption*{\textbf{Note:} #1}\vspace{-\abovecaptionskip}}
```

but keep getting an error when I try to compile. My work-around is to just define the new command `\floatnote` and use that instead of `\caption*`. It's a perfectly fine work-around, but I'm left with the question:

Q: Why doesn't the above `\renewcommand` code work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=colon,tableposition=top,figureposition=bottom]{caption}
%\renewcommand{\caption*}[1]{\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}\caption*{\textbf{Note:} #1}\vspace{-\abovecaptionskip}}
\newcommand{\floatnote}[1]{\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}\caption*{\textbf{Note:} #1}\vspace{-\abovecaptionskip}}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    foo & bar \\
    \midrule
    baz & qux \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  %\caption*{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
  \floatnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
\end{table}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

[image: tab1]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First: you can't say `\renewcommand{\caption*}[1]{...}` no matter what you put in as the replacement text. A `*`-variant is *not* a command by itself: when you say `\caption`, LaTeX peeks at what's coming next and decides whether to perform the normal action (`\caption`) or the variant (`\caption*`).

Second: even if you could, you may not define a command in terms of itself (without taking special precautions, and this is not the case).

If you say `\renewcommand{\foo}{xyz \foo}` then TeX, upon finding `\foo` will dutifully replace it with

```
xyz \foo
```

and so it would replace `\foo` with `xyz \foo` and … TeX will stop when its memory is exhausted.

The strategy of defining `\floatnote` is surely better.

Answer (score 8):

This answer echoes egreg's and gives some more detail.

When using the LaTeX definitions `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand` and `\providecommand`, only letters are allowed in the definition of the control sequence. Sometimes you may use `@`, but this is only allowed after changing the category code from other (or 12) to letter (or 11); hence the call to `\makeatletter`. For a list of TeX's category codes, see [What are category codes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16410/5764) You are allowed other non-letter character constructions, but then you have to use a different (more low-level) control sequence definition/construction.

The way one would (re)define a command that has a `*`-variant would be via "verbatim peeking" - this uses the TeX condition `\@ifstar` (see [Commands defined with `*` options](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=cmdstar)) - or by using constructs that support it, like those provided by [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) or [`suffix`](http://ctan.org/pkg/suffix). Regardless, whether conditioning or using support techniques, you (re)define the unstarred version, and merely supply a `*`-variant.

Here's how you would go about redefining a command to have a `*`-variant using `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\RedefineDocumentCommand{\somecommand}{s ...}{
  % macro contents where #1 refers to *-variant (true) or not (false)
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}% Condition on *
    {}% TRUE: \somecommand*
    {}% FALSE: \somecommand
}
```

Here's how the interface with `suffix` is used:

```
\usepackage{suffix}% http://ctan.org/pkg/suffix
\newcommand\somecommand{...}% unstarred version
\WithSuffix\newcommand\somecommand*{...}% *-variant
```

Comment: Wish I could check two answers. This was very helpful. But I'll just stick with the simpler `\floatnote` method, mentioned above, and not go down this road.