# Use catcode for alternative way of writing fractions

Tags: catcodes, fractions

Writing fractions using different syntax would sometimes be useful, instead of using `\frac{ab}{cd}`, I would prefer to write something like
`\frac{ab⌂cd}`
where the Unicode `⌂` is the `}{`.

**n.b.**, I don't want to mess with the `\frac` definition, but rather something like `\newcommand{\myfrac}[2]{#1⌂#2}`

**Approach**-My understanding of TeX is limited, but I think I can use catcode to do this, My understanding is that:

- `` \catcode `@=2 `` is equivalent to `}`
- `` \catcode `@=1 `` is equivalent to `{`

However just writing

```
\catcode`\⌂=\active
\def ⌂{ \catcode `@=2 \catcode `@=1 }
```

Comment: You can do simpler: `\def\myfrac#1⌂#2{\frac{#1}{#2}}`.

Comment: @Eddy_Em: But then you would still need to introduce grouping braces like `\myfrac25⌂{36}` because `\myfrac25⌂36` would be displayed as `(25/3)6`.

Comment: I add an answer, but be careful in choosing of last symbol (apostrophe in this case): it shouldn't be in argument of `\myfrac`.

Comment: Maybe something like: `\catcode\`⌂=13 \let⌂\over $ {1⌂2} $ \bye`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have koi8-r locale & don't work with unicode, so instead of `⌂` I'll use `|`:

First define a command:

```
\makeatletter
\def\myfrac@#1|#2'{\frac{#1}{#2}}
\def\myfrac#1{\myfrac@#1'}
\makeatother
```

Then use it:

```
example: $\myfrac{10|20}$
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! However, I am wondering if there is  a way to do this along the lines I specified..it would be nice to know my way around catcode

Comment: @georgraba Catcodes have nothing to do with this: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16410/what-are-category-codes for a starter on them.