# Making underscore persistent in LaTeX math mode (for long subscripts)

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

Is there at all a way to make underscores and carets persistent in LaTeX math mode? What I mean, is to be able to write several-character sub/superscripts without using curly brackets. Could LaTeX maybe understand that a white space determines the end of my sub/superscript?

A quick example. I'd like to have something like

```
x_ij y_ij
```

Compile to the same result as

```
x_{ij}y_{ij}
```

I understand that this is probably not a really reliable thing, but I'm looking to take notes faster during class!

Many thanks

Comment: No, it's not reliable. You're very likely to forget a space when typing something like `Let $x_i$ be the least...` which would lead to a long string of weird errors. It would be easier something like `x_ij_` so the subscript is delimited by another `_`

Comment: Related, if not equal: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96080/21930.

Answer (score 1):

Making `_` and `^` active to check wether the next token is `{` or not, and if it is, act as always `_{asdf}`, but if it's not, look until the next space (you cannot end math with `$` for instance without leaving a space before).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\newsb{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\sb}{\sbauto}}
\def\sbauto#1 {\sb{#1}}
\newcommand*\newsp{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\sp}{\spauto}}
\def\spauto#1 {\sp{#1}}

\catcode`\^=\active
\catcode`\_=\active

\AtBeginDocument
 {\catcode`\^=\active
  \catcode`\_=\active
  \let_\newsb
  \let^\newsp}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\sum_{i,j,k}x_ijk y^ijk $ \quad $a_1234 b^4567 - c^u9v d_v77p $

\end{document}
```

Comment: May be more robust is this [other solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96080/21930) by David. I just remembered that I had asked the same question some time ago.