# How to write a definition with variants?

Tags: macros, plain-tex

In TeX I can define, say

`\def\1#1 is #2.{#1 & is & #2.\\}`

and

`\def\2#1 has #2.{#1 & has & #2.\\}`

with an easy usage: 
`\1 Jim Jones is a fictional character.`
and
`\2 Tim Smith has two brothers.`

This gives three columns of a tabular: Jim Jones, is, a fictional character. Similarly in the second case.

Can I write a definition depending on, in this case, is/has so I can write

`\3 Jim Jones is a fictional character.`
and
`\3 Tim Smith has two brothers.`

obtaing the previous results?

Solutions using Lua or expl3 are OK, but I hope that a pure TeX one is also possible.

Comment: At the TeX level for any `\def` you can have only one parameter text (the `#1 is #2.` and `#1 has #2.` in your `\1` and `\2` respectively).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR That's why I am asking how to extend this possibility.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke What if `\3 The third person singular form of have is has` or `\3 Be has is as the third person singular form`? What should it produce? ;-)

Comment: @L.F. I have a limited number of sequences, with different words, so I know it will not happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `listofitems` approach.  Also, `listofitems` is available in Plain TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\def\variant#1.{%
  \setsepchar{is||has}%
  \greadlist*\varinput{#1}
  \varinput[1] & \varinputsep[1] & \varinput[2].
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\variant Jim Jones is a fictional character.\\
\variant Tim Smith has two brothers.
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Similarly done in plain TeX

```
\input listofitems
\def\variant#1.{%
  \setsepchar{is||has}%
  \greadlist*\varinput{#1}
  \varinput[1] \& \varinputsep[1] \& \varinput[2].
}
\variant Jim Jones is a fictional character.

\variant Tim Smith has two brothers.

\bye
```

Comment: Certainly +1. However, I will wait for alternative solutions. And I must reserve 3 days for reading your package. :-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Thanks.  The package idea was mine, but the coding is all Christian's who made it come to life.

Comment: That's really cool! (Note to my self: perhaps that allows one to write a nice coordinate parser for 3d vector operations?)

Comment: @marmot It is the ultimate nested parser.  Here is the ultimate example of it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332012/translate-in-line-equations-to-tex-code-any-package/332061#332061

Comment: Thanks! (Ti*k*Z already has a parser but I have a conceptual/bookkeeping problem. Did you by chance ever teach LaTeX matrix operations like `a = matrix . b` where `a` and `b` are, say, 3d vectors? )

Comment: @marmot I am not sure what you mean by "teach" in this context.  However, look also at my `tabstackengine` package, which uses `listofitems` for parsing.  It can digest matrices and remember all the cell content for future use.

Comment: @marmot For example, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar{\\/&}
\begin{document}
\readlist*\myarray{x11&y12&z13\\x21&y22&z_{23}\\x31&y32&z33}
Row 2, Col 3 = $\myarray[2,3]$; tokens \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\myarray[2,3]}
\end{document}`

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke `listofitems` was developed in response to my ill-fated https://ctan.org/pkg/getargs `getargs` package.  It was a great idea, but just didn't do what needed to be done.  Christian T. took that idea and turned it into `listofitems`.

Answer (score 3):

The `\replacestrings` macro from OPmac can be used:

```
%from OPmac code:
\bgroup \catcode`!=3 \catcode`?=3
\gdef\replacestrings#1#2{\long\def\replacestringsA##1#1{\def\tmpb{##1}\replacestringsB}%
   \long\def\replacestringsB##1#1{\ifx!##1\relax \else\addto\tmpb{#2##1}%
      \expandafter\replacestringsB\fi}%     improved version <May 2016> inspired 
   \expandafter\replacestringsA\tmpb?#1!#1% 
   \long\def\replacestringsA##1?{\def\tmpb{##1}}\expandafter\replacestringsA\tmpb
}
\egroup
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

%variant definition:
\def\variant #1.{\def\tmpb{#1}%
  \replacestrings{ is }{ \tabsep is \tabsep }%
  \replacestrings{ has }{ \tabsep has \tabsep }%
  \tmpb
}
\def\tabsep{&}

%% test:
\halign{#\hfil\vrule\strut\ &#\hfil\vrule\ &# \hfil\cr
%
  \variant Jim Jones is a fictional character. \cr
  \variant Tim Smith has two brothers. \cr
}

\end
```

Answer (score 2):

With `expl3`, of course. `;-)`

```
\input expl3-generic

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \3 #1.
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \s*(is|has)\s* } { \cT\& \1 \cT\& } \l_tmpa_tl
  \l_tmpa_tl. \cr
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\halign{#\hfil&\ \hfil#\hfil\ &# \hfil\cr
  \3 Jim Jones is a fictional character and is funny.
  \3 Tim Smith has two brothers.
}

\bye
```

[image]