# Transforming a statement into a mathematical expression

Tags: equations, luatex, lua, mathematics

Is there a way, where I could automatically transform a string (using a command) like:

```
(1/SF) * (MDD\_a) * (1/LDD\_b) * (MBS\_b) * (1/SSA\_ab)
```

into a mathematical expression like:

```
$(\frac{1}{SF}) * (MDD\_a) * (\frac{1}{LDD\_b}) * (MBS\_b) * (\frac{1}{SSA\_ab})$
```

when then looks like:

[image]

I have several dynamic statements of the above form, which I would automatically transform to a mathematical expression.

Comment: no. as displayed math term i guess that you need to rewrite it into `\[
        \frac{1}{\mathrm{SF}}\mathrm{MDD}_a\frac{1}{\mathrm{LDD}_b}\mathrm{MBS}_b \frac{1}{\mathrm{SSA}_{ab}}
        = \frac{\mathrm{MDD}_a}{\mathrm{SF}}\frac{\mathrm{MBS}_b}{\mathrm{LDD}_b} \frac{1}{\mathrm{SSA}_{ab}} = ...
        \]`

Comment: @Zarko How could I write a command that transforms the text like `(1/SF) * (MDD\_a) * (1/LDD\_b) * (MBS\_b) * (1/SSA\_ab)` into a mathematical expression?

Comment: presumably whatever is generating the original knows it is for tex since it is using `\_` not `_` in which case it would be much more reliable if it generated the fractions using `\frac` rather than an infix /

Comment: as your image shows, do not use math italic for multiple letter identifiers like LDD you should use `\mathrm` as Zarko suggested. The math italic font uses wide spacing between the letters so they look like a product of variables not a single word.

Comment: Which tex editor do you use?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The program outputs a simple string without escaping any character `(1/SF) * (MDD_a) * (1/LDD_b) * (MBS_b) * (1/SSA_ab)`, I was looking for a way, where I could transform this plain string into a mathematical expression.

Comment: Which TeX engine do you use? pdf(La)TeX? Are you willing and able to switch to LuaLaTeX? And, should (say) `MDD\_a` really be rendered with an underscore, or would you rather get `MDD_{a}`, i.e., `a` as a subscript to the right of "MDD"? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I am using LuaLatex

Comment: Thanks. And, must you place parentheses around the terms, or could you let `\frac{1}{SF}` stand by itself?

Comment: Please see this answer, to see if it helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332012/translate-in-line-equations-to-tex-code-any-package/332061#332061

Comment: @Mico Can go without the parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution, which makes use of Lua's powerful `string.gsub` and `string.sub` functions.

[image]

```
%%% Must be compiled under LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function nicemath ( s )
  s = s:gsub ( "%(([%w%_]+)/([%w%_]+)%)","\\frac{%1}{%2}" )
  s = s:gsub ( "(%a+)_(%a+)" , "%1_{%2}" )
  s = s:gsub ( "%u+" , "\\mathrm{%0}" )
  s = s:gsub ( "%*" , "\\cdot " )
  s = s:gsub ( "%b()", function ( x ) return x:sub ( 2 , -2 ) end ) -- optional
  tex.sprint ( s )
end
```

```lua
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\nicemath[1]{\directlua{nicemath(\luastringN{#1})}}

\begin{document}
\[
\nicemath{(1/SF) * (MDD_a) * (1/LDD_b) * (MBS_b) * (1/SSA_ab)}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you place the parentheses a little bit different, you can use ConTeXt's `asciimath` module.

```
\usemodule[asciimath]

\starttext

\startformula
    \asciimath{1/(SF) * MDD_a * 1/(LDD_b) * MBS_b * 1/(SSA_(ab))}
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I start with using the exact and very unusual answer at [Translate in-line equations to TeX code (Any Package?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332012/translate-in-line-equations-to-tex-code-any-package/332061#332061) (no changes) to *interpret* and *translate* the user's input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listofitems,ifthen}

\def\QS[#1]{%
  \if+\Qsep[#1]+\else%
  \if-\Qsep[#1]-\else%
  \if/\Qsep[#1]\over\else%
  \if=\Qsep[#1]=\else%
  \if^\Qsep[#1]^\else%
  \if(\Qsep[#1]\bgroup\left(\else%
  \if)\Qsep[#1]\right)\egroup\else%
  \if[\Qsep[#1]\bgroup\else%
  \if]\Qsep[#1]\egroup\else%
  \if*\Qsep[#1]\cdot\else%
  \if_\Qsep[#1]\expandafter\theund\else%
  \csname \Qsep[#1]\endcsname\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi%
}%

\def\theund#1[#2]{_{\mathrm{#1[#2]}}}%

\setsepchar[@]{=@(||)||[||]@^@/||*@+||-@_@alpha||beta||pi||cos||sin||tan}

\makeatletter

\def\gQ[#1]{\edef\tmp{#1}\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\Z%
  \expandafter{\expandafter\Q\expandafter[\tmp]}}
\def\gQS[#1]{\edef\tmp{#1}\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\Z%
  \expandafter{\expandafter\QS\expandafter[\tmp]}}

\makeatother

\newcommand\interpreteq[1]{%
  \def\Z{}%
  \greadlist*\Q{#1}%
  \presentQ%
  \Z%
}

\newcounter{lindex}
\def\presentQ{% =
  \setcounter{lindex}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{lindex}<\listlen\Q[]}{%
    \stepcounter{lindex}%
    \presentQA[\thelindex]%
    \ifnum\value{lindex}<\listlen\Q[]\relax%
      \gQS[\thelindex]%
    \fi%
  }%
}
\newcounter{lindexA}
\def\presentQA[#1]{% ()
  \setcounter{lindexA}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{lindexA}<\listlen\Q[#1]}{%
    \stepcounter{lindexA}%
    \presentQB[#1,\thelindexA]%
    \ifnum\value{lindexA}<\listlen\Q[#1]\relax%
      \gQS[#1,\thelindexA]%
    \fi%
  }
}
\newcounter{lindexB}
\def\presentQB[#1]{% ^
  \setcounter{lindexB}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{lindexB}<\listlen\Q[#1]}{%
    \stepcounter{lindexB}%
    \presentQC[#1,\thelindexB]%
    \ifnum\value{lindexB}<\listlen\Q[#1]\relax%
      \gQS[#1,\thelindexB]%
    \fi%
  }
}
\newcounter{lindexC}
\def\presentQC[#1]{% /*
  \setcounter{lindexC}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{lindexC}<\listlen\Q[#1]}{%
    \stepcounter{lindexC}%
    \presentQD[#1,\thelindexC]%
    \ifnum\value{lindexC}<\listlen\Q[#1]\relax%
      \gQS[#1,\thelindexC]%
    \fi%
  }
}
\newcounter{lindexD}
\def\presentQD[#1]{% +-
  \setcounter{lindexD}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{lindexD}<\listlen\Q[#1]}{%
    \stepcounter{lindexD}%
    \presentQE[#1,\thelindexD]%
    \ifnum\value{lindexD}<\listlen\Q[#1]\relax%
      \gQS[#1,\thelindexD]%
    \fi%
  }
}
\newcounter{lindexE}
\def\presentQE[#1]{% _
  \setcounter{lindexE}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{lindexE}<\listlen\Q[#1]}{%
    \stepcounter{lindexE}%
    \presentQF[#1,\thelindexE]%
    \ifnum\value{lindexE}<\listlen\Q[#1]\relax%
      \gQS[#1,\thelindexE]%
    \fi%
  }
}
\newcounter{lindexF}
\def\presentQF[#1]{% alpha beta pi cos sin tan
  \setcounter{lindexF}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{lindexF}<\listlen\Q[#1]}{%
    \stepcounter{lindexF}%
    \gQ[#1,\thelindexF]%
    \ifnum\value{lindexF}<\listlen\Q[#1]\relax%
      \gQS[#1,\thelindexF]%
    \fi%
  }
}

% THESE ARE THE REDEFITIIONS FOR TRANSLATION
\usepackage{environ}

\def\QSALT[#1]{%
  \if+\Qsep[#1]+\else%
  \if-\Qsep[#1]-\else%
  \if/\Qsep[#1]\over\else%
  \if=\Qsep[#1]=\else%
  \if^\Qsep[#1]^\else%
  \if(\Qsep[#1]{\left(\else%
  \if)\Qsep[#1]\right)}\else%
  \if[\Qsep[#1]{\else%
  \if]\Qsep[#1]}\else%
  \if*\Qsep[#1]\cdot\else%
  \if_\Qsep[#1]\expandafter\theundALT\else%
  \expandafter\noexpand\csname \Qsep[#1]\endcsname\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi%
}%

\def\theundALT#1[#2]{_{\noexpand\mathrm{#1[#2]}}}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand\translateeq[1]{%
  \bgroup%
  \let\QS\QSALT%
  \def\Z{}%
  \greadlist*\Q{#1}%
  \presentQ%
  \protected@edef\ZZ{\Z}
  \par\medskip\noindent%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\detokenize\expandafter{\ZZ}}%
  \par\medskip%
  \egroup%
}
\makeatother

\NewEnviron{translateeqs}{\expandafter\nexteqn\BODY\par\relax}

\long\def\nexteqn#1\par#2\relax{%
  \translateeq{#1}\ifx\relax#2\else\nexteqn#2\relax\fi%
}
\begin{document}
\textbf{INTERPRETATING EQUATIONS}
\[
\interpreteq{(1/SF) * (MDD\_a) * (1/LDD\_b) * (MBS\_b) * (1/SSA\_ab)}
\]

\textbf{TRANSLATING EQUATIONS}

\translateeq{(1/SF) * (MDD\_a) * (1/LDD\_b) * (MBS\_b) * (1/SSA\_ab)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Modifications can be made to reflect a different appearance.

For example, if `\_` were, inside the definitions of `\interpreteq` and `\translateeq`, redefined as

```
\def\_{_}
```

and added to the parsing list via:

```
\setsepchar[@]{=@(||)||[||]@^@/||*@+||-@_||\_@alpha||beta||pi||cos||sin||tan}
```

then the result would look even better:

[image]

If the OP really wanted an asterisk rather than a `\cdot` in the output, then replacing `\cdot` with `*` in the definition of `\QS` and `\QSALT` would suffice, for example:

```
\def\QS[#1]{%
  \if+\Qsep[#1]+\else%
  \if-\Qsep[#1]-\else%
  \if/\Qsep[#1]\over\else%
  \if=\Qsep[#1]=\else%
  \if^\Qsep[#1]^\else%
  \if(\Qsep[#1]\bgroup\left(\else%
  \if)\Qsep[#1]\right)\egroup\else%
  \if[\Qsep[#1]\bgroup\else%
  \if]\Qsep[#1]\egroup\else%
  \if*\Qsep[#1]*\else%
  \if_\Qsep[#1]\expandafter\theund\else%
  \csname \Qsep[#1]\endcsname\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi%
}%
```

[image]

Comment: I am using lualtex to render the document. As I do `tex.print("$\string\\interpreteq{".. row_val .."}$")`, I get an error saying https://ibb.co/yq1fQ5n

Comment: @Amanda I am unable to access your error (site is blocked to me.).  Plus, I don't speak `lualatex`, which may also be an impediment to my understanding your problem.

Comment: It says, `Ambiguous; you need another { and }. \QS ... \if -\Qsep [#1] -\else \if /\Qsep [#1]\over ..`

Comment: @Amanda I have never seen such a warning and don't know how to interpret it in light of the `listofitems` package.  It might have something to do with the way you structured your `tex.print` command, but I am not the one to help you in that regard.