# shorter method of writing \text{}

Tags: equations, amsmath

I use `\text{}` a lot for subscripts as it make equations look cleaner.

It is however a giant pain to write something like `x_{\text{subscript}}` several times over. Not to mention that it makes the latex code a lot harder to read for mere mortals.

Is there a quicker way of achieving the result of writing `\text{myText}`?

Comment: For one, there's always LyX and similar things.

Comment: I find this question quite useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96080/expanding-subscript-and-subscript-capabilities
It defines a shorthand for these kind of subscripts. There are some issues, but I use it in many documents productively.

Comment: Maybe `\newcommand{\tsub}[2]{#1_{\text{#2}}}`  then using `\tsub{x}{subscript}` --- it's quite semantically sound, imho.

Comment: @Rmano I quite like that one. It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it's a lot better than the alternative :p

Comment: You should almost _never_ use `\text` that makes a non-math region that picks up the current font from outside the math (eg it is italic is an italic theorem)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is for an engineering report so I'm alright for now, but thanks for the heads up. Does `\textrm{}` solve this?

Comment: @iHnR normally `\mathrm` but as Rmano notes you can't currently use that for accented letters, so textrm if you need that

Answer (score 1):

Forcing with strange catcodes changes the standard behavior of `_` and `^` is quite for sure a call to have problems down the way (Ti*k*Z? `babel`?). I also use a lot plain text subscripts; I suggest a semantic definition:

```
\newcommand{\tsub}[2]{#1_{\textrm{#2}}}
\newcommand{\maxval}[1]{\tsub{#1}{máx}}
```

(for example) and then you can use (notice that it's quite clear what the semantic is, and you have just one point of update if you want to change language...)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\tsub}[2]{#1_{\textrm{#2}}}
\newcommand{\maxval}[1]{\tsub{#1}{máx}}
\begin{document}

$a+\tsub{b}{medio}=\maxval{c}$

\end{document}
```

[image: output from the above snippet]

(Yes, `\textrm`¹ and not `\mathrm` otherwise you can't use `máx`...)

---

¹ thanks @DavidCarlisle...

Comment: `\textrm` otherwise it'll be italic in theorems

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a custom macro as a little wrapper:

```
\newcommand{\t}[1]{\text{#1}}
```

Then you can use `\t{myText}` instead of `\text{myText}`.

EDIT: As was pointed out in the comments, `\t` is already taken. So either choose a different name or - if you don't need the original `\t` anywhere in your document - use `\renewcommand` instead to overwrite the definition of `\t`. This might have other unintended side-effects though, so that's probably not the best idea.

Comment: you didn't try that: `! LaTeX Error: Command \t already defined.`

Comment: See also [Short names for macros - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/short-names-for-macros)

Comment: Apart from not using `\t` are you sure the OP wants `\text` (eg have the text italic in a theorem)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer indeed I did not. I was merely trying to illustrate the underlying concept. Thanks for pointing this out though. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well that's what was asked for, so that's what I based by answer on. Whether this is really the behavior that OP is after, I don't know ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32722915#32722915