# Automatic subscript command

Tags: macros

I am working on a document that has a lot of subscripts. I am getting really tired typing the `_`. Is there a way to do the following:

Everytime I want `$v_1$`, I just want to type in `v1`. Or `b1` produces `b_1` or `c1` produces `c_1`.

Bonus points for someone who can teach me how to do something like `b{1 and 2}` for `b_{1 and 2}` or something even more robust where I can specify whether its a superscript or a subscript.

I understand this might end up in more keystrokes but I'd rather have simple keystrokes than moving my hand across the keyboard for the underscore.

*I also realized I don't  use the number pad. Is there a way to hotkey the number pad so that press "1" on the number pad will insert `\textbf{}` for me or something similar -- this might be posted as another question*

Comment: see recent questions for reasons why it's a bad idea to do this, and possible solutions if you wish to do it anyway [Expanding subscript and subscript capabilities](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96080) and [alternative syntax of subscripts using tex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96073)

Comment: Regarding your question about "hotkeys", this is a feature of your editor, not of TeX/LaTeX, and as such it is off-topic on this site.  Regarding your main question, I am not sure what you want: is it that any digit following a letter should be subscripted?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Yes. Any series of numbers should be subscripted. b2343 means b_2343

Comment: If zou might the difficultz of tzping _ then zou could trz a different kezboard lazout. The German lazout has the _ kez just left the shift kez, making it easilz accessible. But, there are drawbacks: the y and z kez are exchanged for example...

Comment: I see. I believe you might be using a different layout where your z is switched with y :)

Answer (score 2):

This is implemented in [mhchem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) package:  `\ce{H20}` produces an equivalent to `$\mathrm{H}_2\mathrm{O}$`.  You may want to either use this package directly or look into its code to borrow ideas.

Comment: I think the OP asks for a way without the `\ce{}` macro letting TeX parse the scripts.

Comment: Yes, and this is why I recommended looking into the code to implement a similar environment or global switch.

Comment: Chemical formulas are very specialized and one can assume that every number (after a letter) in them is a subscript; what about `$b1+1$`? And `b23` should mean `b_{2}^{3}`, `b_{23}`, `b^{23}` or `b^{2}_{3}`?

Comment: b23 should mean b_{23}. I am not worried about superscripts, but if there IS a way to do it (i cant see a way) then I would appreciate that knowledge also

Comment: Well, Martin Hensel put some nice heuristics in the package:  `\ce{b1+c}` means `$b_1^+ c$`, while `\ce{b1 + c}` means `$b_1 + c$`, `\ce{b23}` means `$b_{23}$` etc.  You always can use explicit `_` and `^` with grouping to override, but defaults work fine in 90% of cases and turn out to be very useful when you quickly type, e.g. making notes during a talk.  I agree that outside of chemistry a different set of defaults should be designed.

Comment: I believe that should be sufficient for my needs. Thanks.