# String operation creates error in pgfmathsetmacro

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, strings, xstring

I am trying to reference the first character of a string within a `pgfmathsetmacro`, however, the macro `\StrLeft` from `xstring`, I believe, is not playing well with `pgfmathsetmacro`.

Take the following example that replicates this problem:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{xstring}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \newcommand{\str}{hello};
        \newcommand{\firstChar}
        {
            \StrLeft{\str}{1}
        };

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\halfStr}{width("\str") * 1pt / 2cm};
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\halfFirstChar}{width("\firstChar") * 1pt / 2cm};

        \node at (0, 0) {\str};
        \draw [color=black] (\halfFirstChar - \halfStr, 0cm) -- (\halfFirstChar - \halfStr,-1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

The following code should output the following:

[image: Vertical Line in the middle of the 'h' in 'hello'.]

*(The string "hello" printed, along with a vertical line beginning from the halfway point of the "h" character and then moving downwards 1 centimeter.)*

However, `\halfFirstChar` generates an error that reads:

> Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }. Runaway argument? Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

I am able to print `\firstChar` without any problems by doing the following:

```
    % ...
    \node at (0, 0) {\firstChar};
    % ...
```

However, I am unable to reference `\firstChar` within `\halfFirstChar`. **Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this error and a solution to this problem?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit tricky because of expansion issues. The perhaps easiest way to make it work is to use the optional argument of `\StrLeft` to define `\firstChar`. Then the rest works as it should, I think.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\str}{hello}
    \StrLeft{\str}{1}[\firstChar]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\halfStr}{width("\str") * 1pt / 2cm};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\halfFirstChar}{width("\firstChar") * 1pt / 2cm};

    \node at (0, 0) {\str};
    \draw [color=black] (\halfFirstChar - \halfStr, 0cm) -- (\halfFirstChar - \halfStr,-1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I believe to also sense where the journey may go. You need to be a bit careful since nodes have `outer` and `inner` `sep`s, which may affect the position, but you can set those to `0`. And actually you do not need the `\pgfmathsemacro` thingy, the Ti*k*Z parser is very versatile, it even understands `pt`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\str}{hello}
    \StrLeft{\str}{1}[\firstChar]
    \node[inner sep=0] at (0, 0) {\str};
    \draw [color=black] ({(width("\firstChar")/2-width("\str")/2)*1pt}, 0cm) 
    -- ++ (0,-1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And of course you can change the font size in nodes, which may also affect these tricks. I am actually wondering if you want to have a look at the `tikzmark` library and check what has been done there. (BTW, you need no `;` after `\newcommand{...}{...}`.)

Comment: What do you mean by "expansion issues?" I guess I am confused about what sort of syntax and/or "rules" I am breaking in LaTeX when I wrote my original example above?

Comment: @DanHoynoski Certainly a comment and not even a full answer will provide enough space to answer that. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158827/121799) is an answer to that. Basically if you have `\macro{\anothermacro}` it matters if `\anothermacro` is "expanded" or some "hull" that expands to something when you, well, expand it. Please have a look at the link... ;-)

Comment: @DanHoynoski Basically, `\StrLeft` is a set of instructions to _typeset_ the left-most character, which is not the same as the character itself.