# Bamboozling Arithmetic!

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, arithmetic

While creating some `pgfmathsetmacro` arithmetic macros, I stumbled upon a very perplexing result. Take the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\boxWidth}{6cm};
    \newcommand{\boxHeight}{1cm};

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\boxOffset}{\boxWidth / 2cm * 1cm} %%%wtf
    \coordinate (Title) at (1cm + \boxOffset,0);

    \draw [red] (0,0) -- (1,0);

    \node[draw, rounded corners=.3cm, color=red, minimum width=\boxWidth, minimum height=\boxHeight, text=black] at (Title) {Hello};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This outputs a very predictable result:
[image: predictable result]

However, if you remove `* 1cm` from my `\boxOffset` macro, a totally unexpected result occurs:
[image: unexpected output]

**What?!** On the surface, this appears to be saying that `2 * 1 != 2` is a  true statement!

To add to this, while I was playing around with creating an example LaTeX script for [the following question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454590/string-operation-creates-error-in-pgfmathsetmacro) on this forum, I stumbled upon a similar *bamboozling arithmetic*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\str}{hello};

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\numOne}{width("\str") * 1pt / 4cm}; %%%wtf

    \node at (0, 0) {\str};
    \draw [color=black] (\numOne, 0cm) -- (\numOne,-1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The following example creates the *very predictable* output:

[image: another predictable output]

However, if I change the `\numOne` to compute the following `width("\str") * 1pt / 2cm / 2cm`, then I get a *very unpredictable* output:

[image: another very unpredictable output]

**What?!** This is telling me that the ridiculous statement `x / 2 / 2 != x / 4` is true.

**Can anyone shed some light on what is happening here?** This is not the only time I have run into this *bamboozling arithmetic* and I am lost at what is happening.

[image: bamboozle doggo]

^This is how I feel right now.

Comment: All arithmetic is performed internally in `pt`, so the `1cm` is converted to `28.45274pt`.

Comment: The result is stored in unit `pt`; with `*1cm` you get `85.35823`, without it is `3.0`; the quotient is `28.45274`, which is the number of points in 1cm.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your assumption that multiplying by 1cm is the same as multiplying by 1 is wrong.

What about multiplying by 1in or 1mm?

The function `\pgfmathresult` returns a number, not a dimension. For implementation reasons, the number 1 is stored as a length, precisely 1pt.

Therefore `3*1` is `3`, but `3*1cm` is `85.35823`, because `1cm=28.45275pt` (and then TeX’s rounding applies).

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to address this is to see what the difference between the two calculations yield for `\boxOffset`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\boxWidth}{6cm}
\newcommand{\boxHeight}{1cm}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\boxOffset}{\boxWidth / 2cm}%
\verb|\boxOffset| 1: \boxOffset

\pgfmathsetmacro{\boxOffset}{\boxWidth / 2cm * 1cm}%
\verb|\boxOffset| 2: \boxOffset

\end{document}
```

In performing the division `6cm / 2cm`, [`tikz`](//ctan.org/pkg/tikz) converts the quantities to a uniform unit of measure (`pt`s). However, in this case with similar measurements in the division, it results in merely "striping" the measurement, yielding in `3`. This is understandable. Multiplying this result by `1cm`, the value is first converted to `pt`s (there are 28.45274 `pt`s in every `cm`; see `\newlength{\templen} \setlength{\templen}{1cm} \the\templen`), yielding the desired result (3 x 28.45274 = 85.35822), with some floating point error.

A similar argument would hold for your other calculations as lengths are converted to `pt`s before performing the arithmetic.