# How does \let effect when combined with \@gobble?

Tags: macros, latex-base, definition

I read everywhere (e.g. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/let) that `\let` copies the content of a command into a new command.

My question is, why do we expect `\let\comdwithtwoargs\@gobble` makes \comdwithtwoargs have one argument?

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cmd}[3]{%
    #1 #2 #3
    \let\cmd\@gobble
}
\makeatother

\cmd{abcdef} \cmd{abc}
```

In the example above, the code wouldn't run if I remove `\let\cmd\@gobble`. I don't understand the effect of `\let` and `\@gobble` and how they work.

Comment: By `\let`ting `\cmd` to `\@gobble`, the macro `\cmd` loses all of its original meaning (it is no longer a macro that takes two arguments or does anything), except to gobble the next argument.

Comment: hm, I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but if you define a command with 3 arguments, you should also use it with 3 argument, so `\cmd{a}{b}{c}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's why I am confused. Normally if we have a cmd with 3 args, it doesn't run without error if we use it like `\cmd{arg1}`, but it does run normally in the example.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Now I understand. Nothing special for \@gobble.

Comment: Since `\cmd` actually has three arguments the code in the example does not really do what one would naively expect. In `\cmd{abcdef} \cmd{abc}` the first `\cmd` reads three arguments: Its first argument is `abdcdef`, its second argument is `\cmd` and its third argument is `abc`. Then it expands to `#1 #2 #3`, so we get `abcdef \cmd abc`, so the second `\cmd` which at that point has not been redefined grabs its three arguments, which are (because there are no `{` and `}`s) `a`, `b` and `c` in that order and itself expands to `a b c`. So you end up with `abdcdef a b c`. ...

Comment: well the first \cmd received the argument `{abcdef}` `\cmd`  `{abc}` and outputs them unchanged (but without the braces. then the second `\cmd` gets the arguments `a` `b `c ` and puts them back in the output. I don't think it should matter if the \let is there or not, but perhaps you didn't show everything.

Comment: ... Then `\cmd` is `\let` to `\@gobble`. But this doesn't matter any more, since `\cmd` is not used after that. This is something wildly different from what one would expect if one were to call the macro with the correct number of arguments. If `\cmd` had been defined as `\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{#1 let\cmd\@gobble}` so that it just takes one argument `\cmd{abcdef} \cmd{abc}` would have resulted in just `abcdef` in the output: The first call `\cmd{abdcdef}` would have expanded to `abcdef \let\cmd\@gobble` and would have redefined `\cmd` to just eat its argument. Then `\cmd{abc}` produces no output

Comment: Ohh, commands can receive arguments even if the arguments aren't in braces, e.g. they can receive `\something` as an argument. I see. Thank you @UlrikeFischer and @moewe

Comment: Yes, TeX will always try and read the the specified number of arguments. Unbraced content will be grabbed token-by-token (https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/What_is_a_%22TeX_token%22%3F).

Comment: Thank you @moewe for referencing the article. That's really helpful and I really appreciate it!

Comment: Re tokens, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104023/35864

Comment: Oh yeah. I gotta learn some basics. Thank you @moewe !

Answer (score 5):

In comments it has been explained what is happening so let me take the opportunity to show how tex can show what it is doing, turning on `\tracinngmacros` and `\tracingonline` (so it logs on the terminal and not just in the log)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


aaa % just to get font setup out of the way

{
\tracingonline=1
\tracingmacros=1

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cmd}[3]{%
    #1 #2 #3
    \let\cmd\@gobble
}
\makeatother

\cmd{abcdef} \cmd{abc}

}

\end{document}
```

produces a terminal output

```
\cmd #1#2#3->#1 #2 #3 \let \cmd \@gobble 
#1<-abcdef
#2<-\cmd 
#3<-abc

\cmd #1#2#3->#1 #2 #3 \let \cmd \@gobble 
#1<-a
#2<-b
#3<-c
```

So in the first call to `\cmd` the three arguments are `abcdef`, `\cmd` and `abc`

so abcdef gets typeset then `#2` `#3` is `\cmd abc` so tex then logs the second call to `\cmd` this time the three arguments are `a`, `b` and `c` so it typesets `a b c`  then defines `\cmd` to be `\@gobble` (twice) but the redefined `\cmd` is never called.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The `\tracing...` commands really help!