# Space vs "\ " in TeX

Tags: spacing, pdftex

On page 5 of the book **The TeXbook**, there is

> If your keyboard does not contain a left-quote symbol, you can type `\lq`, followed by a space if the next character is a letter, or followed by a `\` if the next character is a space. Similarly, `\rq` yields a right-quote character. Is that clear?

```
\lq\lq I understand.\rq\rq\ (the last character is a space)
```

[image]

There are two things confusing me:

1. Why add a space at the end of the text?
2. What is the difference between   and `\` , that is space vs `\space`

Comment: Explicit spaces are gobbled after control sequences. If you just typed `...\rq\rq (...`  then the parenthesis would be attached to the right-quote.

Comment: @campa But in the book, there is nothing after the `\ `.

Comment: There is a space.

Comment: @campa  Okay. Now I know that if there isn't `\ `, the space will no longer exist there. But is there a difference between space and `\space`?

Comment: To address your second question: Do you understand the difference between `\lq\lq I understand` and `\lq\lq\ I understand`?

Comment: @Mico  No, I guess there is difference but I don't know.

Comment: That's explained on page 8 `:-)` Keep reading!

Comment: @campa I will learn that tomorrow. I hope I can understand it tomorrow.

Comment: In the former case, there will be no whitespace between the quotation characters and the word "I". In the latter case, there will be a space, because "`\ `" tells TeX to, well, insert a space.

Comment: @Mico  The former case and the latter case are all refer to the last character in `\lq\lq I understand.\rq\rq\ `, so there are always  a whitespace between the quotation  characters and the word "I".

Comment: @Y.zeng - No! There will be whitespace between the opening quotes (generated by `\lq\lq`) and the word "I" only if you change `\lq\lq I understand` to either `\lq\lq\ I understand` or `\lq\lq\space I understand`.

Comment: @Mico Yes. I was confused before. What is the latter case? I have one case in the question.

Answer (score 3):

When converting the input into *[tokens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104023/4427)* (which is what TeX really works with) TeX will ignore spaces following a *control word*, that is, a control sequence starting with a backslash followed by letters, see [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091/4427)

If you input

```
\rq\rq (the last character is a space)
```

there will be *no* space between the closing double quote and the parenthesis when you look at the printout.

You can obviate the problem in two ways

```
\rq\rq\ (the last character is a space)
\rq\rq{} (the last character is a space)
```

They have pros and cons. Look at the difference between

```
Donald said \lq\lq Good-bye.\rq\rq\ After that he left.

Donald said \lq\lq Good-bye.\rq\rq{} After that he left.
```

[image]

Do you see what happens? In the first case, the period is not considered as sentence ending, as it should. This is because `\`  (backslash space) resets the space factor to 1000, besides inserting a space. In the second case this doesn't happen, because `{}` doesn't influence the space factor.

Of course the input

```
Donald said ``Good-bye.'' After that he left.
```

doesn't suffer from the problem.

What's the difference between an explicit space (that survives tokenization) and `\space`? That the latter is a macro expanding to an explicit space. So you might do

```
Donald said \lq\lq Good-bye.\rq\rq\space After that he left.
```

and you'd get the same as with `{}`.

***Note.*** Answers at the linked post about spaces after commands suggest `\xspace`: don't use it (besides, it isn't available in plain TeX).

Comment: Thanks. There are some question confusing me: 
1. Why `\ ` will reset space factor but `\space` won't?
2. If the space factor to 1000 is not the sentence ending, what number is the sentence endning?
3. How did you know the 1000 and what is its meaning?

Comment: @Y.zeng Backslash-space resets the space factor to 1000 because Knuth so decided; on the other hand, `\space` is (mostly) equivalent to typing a space, so no reset of the space factor happens. You should read more about the space factor in TeX by Topic or the TeXbook: it's well explained.

Comment: Okay. I am reading that book very slowly to understand it.