# "\show\ " outputs the "^^M" in TeX?

Tags: primitives

On page 10 of the book **The TeXbook**, it says that `\show\cs`, where `\cs` is any control sequence, can output its meaning. For example, `\show\thinspace` outputs

```latex
> \thinspace=macro:
->\kern .16667em .
```

Why does `\show\`  output:

```
> \^^M=macro:
->\ .
```

Why is there `^^M` here? I knew the `^^M` refers to the enter key in keyboard, but may you tell me the reason?

Comment: I am comfused why the titile was needed to be changed to \show\" instead of "\show\ " and why the **why** was changed to **where**.

Comment: I changed it because you are showing the end-of-line command

Comment: @JosephWright But "\show\" wouldn't output "^^M"

Comment: @JosephWright But why 'where'? The original made sense. I don't understand the 'where'?

Comment: @Y.zeng It will, but it is arguably a slightly different question. For example, David wouldn't need to mention space-stripping if the space weren't there.

Comment: @Y.zeng Er, not sure how that happened: I've fixed

Comment: @cfr I have tested and comfirm that it will. So, there is no difference between "\show\" and "\show\ "? It is weird.

Comment: As David says in his answer, TeX strips spaces at end-of-lines before tokenization,  so ``\ [end-of-line]`` and ``\[end-of-line]`` are identical

Comment: @Y.zeng Because the ` ` is at the end of the line, it gets removed from the input stream. So `\show\ <end of line>` becomes `\show\<end of line>`.

Comment: @JosephWright There is a question, I can add `%` symbol at the end of the line. But if it is "\show\", I can't add `%` after it. If we can add, we can tell the difference.

Comment: @cfr  Do you see this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699598/space-vs-in-tex?noredirect=1#comment1738912_699598 , which says the last space can be added by `\ `. Is `\show` cause the last space removed?

Comment: @Y.zeng OK, I've reverted as this is clearly part of what is confusing you

Comment: @Y.zeng The `\ ` there is because the macro right before would otherwise swallow the space. But `\ ` at the end of a line won't stop TeX removing the space.

Comment: @cfr If the space at the end of the line is removed, what is the meaning of the last "\"  in 
"\show\"?  The last "\" has no meaning.

Comment: @Y.zeng That's formally a different question - `\[newline]` is the control sequence you get with `[newline]` - it's just a character like `[space]` or `a` or whatever, so can be used to make one

Comment: @Y.zeng It applies to the new line. So you get an escaped new line, maybe.

Comment: @JosephWright If "\show\ " equals to "\show\", this means that nothing can be added after the backslash, since there may not be a next line after the text. **The TeXbook** doesn't say this.

Comment: @cfr If there is no new line after it?

Comment: @Y.zeng As David has explained, this happens because TeX strips end-of-line spaces - if you had the ``\show\ `` in the middle of a line of other content, it would be different

Comment: @JosephWright As both of us know, what you get from \ at the end of a line of .tex-input also depends on the value of `\endlinechar` at the time of reading/pre-processing the line of .tex-input in question. The question is about the control sequence token whose name is formed by the carriage return character whose codepoint is 13(dec) in ASCII. Probably that token can colloquially be called "control carriage return" like in the TeXbook the control sequence token whose name is formed by the space character, whose codepoint is 32(dec) in ASCII, is called control space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the behaviour of non printable characters in tex output is customisable by the tcx options on the commandline but by default a newline is shown as `^^M` (character 13)  and `\`  at  the end of a line is `\<newline>`  that is `\^^M` as the space character is stripped by TeXs file reading routines before the input is tokenised.  If you end the line with `\ %` then you will get a `\`  shown as the control sequence will have name space not name newline.

Comment: And plain.tex, line 505 defines `\^^M` as `\ `.

Comment: May you tell why `^^M` represents the character 13? Do you feel `^^M` is a little weird?

Comment: @Y.zeng if you subtract 32 (0x40) to `M` you have the ASCII code of the carriage return. See https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/ASCII-Table-wide.svg. This is why the character with code zero can be written `^^@`, etc...

Comment: It is the TeX syntax for ctrl-M which is carriage return, `\r` just as `^^J` is ctrl-J which is newline `\n` .  This is not tex specific (apart from the `^^` syntax), ctrl-m  has end of line behaviour in general.

Comment: @Rmano the ASCII code of the `M` is 77. 77-32=45. But the carriage return is 13.  Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @Y.zeng the offset for ctrl is 64 not 32

Comment: @Y.zeng is that I forgot my multiplication, I am better in hex than in decimal (yep, 4x16 is *not* 32)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  So `^^` represents `ctrl` key?

Comment: @Rmano  May you tell me why there is 4x16?

Comment: @Y.zeng well it's not documented as that, it is documented as offsetting by 64, but ctrl is defined the same way (unless you have a non standard keyboard mapping, so yes)

Comment: `0x40` in hexadecimal -> 4*16=64 in decimal

Comment: @Rmano Where did you find `0x40`? By your link I only find the `4D`.

Comment: @Y.zeng just standard way to write hex numbers. 4 is the high nibble of 4D, 4D-40=D... Using 0x in front of a number is almost a standard way to say it's hexadecimal.

Comment: @wipet yes latex the same (line 565 of latex.ltx)

Comment: Why did you say `\<newline>` and not `\<carriage return>`? || Probably it is worth mentioning that a backslash character (trailed by some space characters) at the end of a line of .tex-input being tokenized as a control sequence token whose name is formed by the carriage return character is due to `\endlinechar` usually having the value 13? And iirc it was you who drew my attention towards the circumstance that with some implementations of TeX (deviating from what is written in the TeXbook) not only space characters but also horizontal tab characters at the right ends of lines are stripped.;-)

Comment: Why `^^M` represents the character 13? TeX's ^^⟨character⟩-notation is leaned on [caret-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) for non-printable ASCII-control-characters. And caret-notation in turn is designed so that in most cases the character whose codepoint is the number k in ASCII is represented by means of the k-th letter of the latin alphabet. E.g., M is the 13th letter in the latin alphabet.

Comment: @UlrichDiez well since tex normalizes 10, 13, and 10-13 pairs on input  (to `\endlinechar`=13) the names are a bit arbitrary to be honest.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So the point of view is what a user might have typed. Now I got it. Thanks. ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle linefeed, carriage return and linefeed-carriage return all being treated as end of line when reading input - am I right when assuming that this is specified neither in the TeXbook nor in TeX the program, but is a peculiarity of Web2C-implementations?

Comment: @UlrichDiez tex just assumes that the input consists of "lines" it does not have to be a stream with separator characters could be a record based system, or punched card per line or whatever, so yes this is web2c but explicitly authorised system-specific part of tex.web

Comment: @UlrichDiez web2c is a "well-developed pascal site" :-)  Since the inner loop of |input_ln| is part of \TeX's ``inner loop''---each
character of input comes in at this place---it is wise to reduce system
overhead by making use of special routines that read in an entire array
of characters at once, if such routines are available. The following
code uses standard \PASCAL\ to illustrate what needs to be done, but
finer tuning is often possible at well-developed \PASCAL\ sites.
@^inner loop@>