# How to make work macros work as values in parameters of psbarcode?

Tags: pdftex, automation, pst-barcode

## TL;DR-

Works

```
\psbarcode{NODATA}{height=0.33 width=1.6 includecheck includetext}{code128}
```

But "parametrized", does not work as expected (produces big transparent output)

```
\def\h{0.33}
\def\w{1.6}
\psbarcode{NODATA}{height=\h width=\w includecheck includetext}{code128}
```

Reason: I'd love to allow user to specify those `\h` and `\w` as parameter on commandline following [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1495/7128).

## To be more specific

Given : `nodata.tex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % pdflatex require -shell-escape option!!!
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
\psbarcode{NODATA}{height=0.33 width=1.6 includecheck includetext}{code128}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

with

```
$ pdflatex -shell-escape nodata.tex && convert -density 300x300 nodata.{pdf,png} && display nodata.png
```

generated properly `nodata.pdf` and `nodata.png`:

[image]

However when I change psbarcode parameters to use `\h` `\w`, i.e. `\psbarcode{NODATA}{height=\h width=\w includecheck includetext}{code128}` it stops rendering, and results in big transparent output. Full working differently then expected code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % pdflatex require -shell-escape option!!!
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
\def\h{0.33}
\def\w{1.6}
\def\d{DATA}
\psbarcode{\d}{height=\h width=\w includecheck includetext}{code128}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Rendering same but smaller resolution (30x30), as it results **big**:

```
$ pdflatex -shell-escape nodata.tex && convert -density 30x30 nodata.{pdf,png} && display nodata.png
```

Big transparent output, for completeness:

[image]

Comment: Could please someone add more tags if some are appropriate for issues with parametrizing using `\def` ?

Comment: Why not use `\newcommand\barcode[2]{\psbarcode{NODATA}{height=#1 width=#2 includecheck includetext}{code128}}` ?

Comment: I like your idea @Andrew . Did you consider adding also a bit about this use case of "#1" into http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123186/7128 ? Imho it's not clearly visible there and might help some users. Why do I still want to use `\def\Key{Val}` way? Still, giving ability to name parameters in "key1=val1,key2=val2" manner, has still some advantages. In my case I'd like to allow multiple optional arguments for tex template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the key-value pairs are separated by spaces and in

```
\psbarcode{NODATA}{height=\h width=\w includecheck includetext}{code128}
```

there is *no* space after `\h` and `\w`, because they're ignored at tokenization time.

I tried with `height={\h}` or `{height=\h}` but neither works. A workaround is to define the macros with a parameter text:

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % pdflatex require -shell-escape option!!!
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
\def\h/{0.33}
\def\w/{1.6}
\psbarcode{NODATA}{height=\h/ width=\w/ includecheck includetext}{code128}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively:

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % pdflatex require -shell-escape option!!!

\newcommand{\psbarcodemacro}[3]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\psbarcode{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }\x
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
\def\h{0.33 }
\def\w{1.6 }
\psbarcodemacro{NODATA}{height=\h width=\w includecheck includetext}{code128}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please also give a hint how to make your mathod work with barcode data/payload?
I've tried the same `\def\d/{Data} \psbarcodemacro{\d/}` but it does not work. (Before asking I've poked around various TeX/LaTeX topics like `\xdef`, `\expandafter`, `\csname` ... and got lost ). Thanks for `\def\h/` , for width and height is works perfectly!

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki I've no idea what “payload” is. If you are meaning the first argument, I see no problem with both approaches (the second one might give some if special characters in the data are used).

Comment: Yes, by "data/payload" I've meant first argument. Now I see where things break. Still don't know solution. So if I specify `\def\d/{in tex file}` in tex file, then it works. But if I remove definition from `.tex` file and try to specify via command line, by calling: `pdflatex -shell-escape '\def\d/{DATA} \input{t.tex}' ` , then `\psbarcodemarco` produces strange barcode, like containing sth else then just "DATA" : http://imgur.com/1gEDuuv . Somehow defining in commandline differs from defining in tex file - but I am afraid it's might be of scope of this question and topic for another:)

Comment: (The same with `\h/` and `\w/` they behave differently when defined via command line instead of "in tex" file - still I am aware it's out of scope of  this question)

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki I get nothing strange if I do `pdflatex -shell-escape '\def\NO{NODATA}\input{file}`, with `\psbarcode{\NO}{...}{...}`.

Comment: Here I've made minimal not-working example, basically, copy&paste of your code and it does not work with `\psbarcode{\NO}'  and '\def\NO{DATA}' supplied via command line , here is verbatim code: http://pastebin.com/0v4P3bY6 and here is effect: http://imgur.com/425mXGg .

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki I'm afraid it can't work, unless you pass the correct command line also when `latex` is called from inside the compilation.

Answer (score 3):

Let a space in the  `\def` or use `\space` in `\psbarcode`

```
\documentclass[border=4,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % pdflatex require -shell-escape option!!!
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-0.2)(1.6in,0.5in)
    \def\h{0.33 }
    \def\w{1.6 }
\psbarcode{NODATA}{height=\h width=\w includecheck includetext}{code128}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-0.2)(1.6in,0.5in)
    \def\h{0.33}
    \def\w{1.6}
    \psbarcode{NODATA}{height=\h\space width=\w\space includecheck includetext}{code128}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

from a command line you can run

```
xelatex --shell-escape "\def\d{DATA} \def\w{0.33} \def\h{1.6} \input{t.tex}"
```

Comment: Do you know how to parametrize it so user can specify `\h` `\w` `\d` (`\d` instead of "NODATA") from command line in manner: `pdflatex -shell-escape '\def\d/{DATA} \def\w/{0.33} \def\h/{1.6} \input{t.tex}` ? I am aware this might be out of scope of this question, but maybe, by chance you know :).

Comment: use `xelatex` then the command line is possible, see edited answer

Comment: I've tried `xelatex -shell-escape '\def\NO{DATA}\input{egreg_v3d.tex}'` with http://pastebin.com/0v4P3bY6 and got http://imgur.com/ajfuwmP , so it passes "data" but has trouble with automatic cropping. And as finally I'd love user to be able to specify different sizes, it recalculating manual cropping does not sound like incentive. Still, thanks! I've read more about xelatex and now I see what kind of benefits it might bring, and that it's part of TeX Live, so it should be widely available.

Comment: You have to pass values to the pspicture environment. If they are missing it uses an area of 10cm x 10cm. See the values in my example

Comment: Now I have also xelatex alternative if at any day pdflatex would turn against me :). Thank you for a lot of help! :)