# A beamer buggy handling of newcommand?

Tags: beamer

Does anyone know why I get error here? Analogous code works for document class "slides" in latex.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\newcommand{\sld}{\end{frame} \begin{frame}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Test -- Page 1
\sld
Test -- Page 2
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)'s `frame` environment is very complicated, since it has to deal with the *overlay specification* - something inherent to `beamer` that the end-user rarely have to worry about. That is, you set what looks like a single `frame` environment, while `beamer` translates it into a number of *slides* (possibly).

`beamer` also reads the *entire* `frame` environment in order to manage multiple instances of it and technically misses your `\sld`'s `\end{frame}`. Other  document classes have other ways of managing this, since they don't provide/lack `beamer` *overlay specification*, and as such only processes `frame`s once.

---

Here is a more lengthy and detailed discussion:

This procedure of taking "one thing" (a single `frame` environment) and replicating it into "multiple things" (numerous *slides*) requires `beamer` to grab the entire `frame` environment *before* starting to process it. We can see this "`frame` grabbing" when you look at certain components inside [`beamerbaseframe.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbaseframe.sty):

```
%
% The frame environment (a trifle ugly...)
%

% Copyright notice: the following code is adapted from code from the
% amsmath package.

\newtoks\beamer@envbody
\def\beamer@frameenv{%
  \def\beamer@process@envbody{\endgroup%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\beamer@framecommand\expandafter\beamer@frameoptions\expandafter{\the\beamer@envbody}}%
  \global\beamer@envbody{}\def\beamer@begin@stack{b}%
  \begingroup
  \let\frame\beamer@collect@@body
  \def\beamer@process@envbody{\frame}%
  \beamer@process@envbody%
}

% Normally not executed; only in containsverbatim context:
\def\endframe{\egroup\begingroup\def\@currenvir{frame}}

\long\def\beamer@push@begins#1\begin#2{\ifx\end#2\else b\expandafter\beamer@push@begins\fi}
\long\def\beamer@collect@@body#1\end#2{%
  \def\test{#1}%
  \edef\beamer@begin@stack{\beamer@push@begins#1\begin\end \expandafter\@gobble\beamer@begin@stack}%
  \ifx\@empty\beamer@begin@stack
      \global\beamer@envbody\expandafter{\the\beamer@envbody#1}%
    \def\reserved@a{#2}
    \ifx\reserved@a\beamer@frametext%
      \endgroup%
      \let\@next=\beamer@process@envbody % A little tricky! Note the grouping
      \@checkend{#2}%
    \else%
      % ok, just expand it, presumably it will generate the desired \end{frame}
      \let\@next=\beamer@process@expander%
    \fi
  \else
    \global\beamer@envbody\expandafter{\the\beamer@envbody#1\end{#2}}%
    \let\@next=\beamer@process@envbody%
  \fi
  \@next
}
```

Note how `\beamer@frameenv` - fundamentally, the start of the `frame` environment, calls `\beamer@process@envbody`, which expands to `\frame`, which expands to `\beamer@collect@@body`. Further down we see that `\beamer@collect@@body`'s *parameter* text is defined to include `\end`. More specifically,

```
\long\def\beamer@collect@@body#1\end#2{...}
```

This means that the macro grabs everything from the start of the environment up until `\end` into argument `#1`, and the environment name as the argument to `\end` in argument `#2`. At the stage of grabbing these arguments (not only are the [category codes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16410/5764) fixed, but also) TeX has to *see* a visible `\end`.

In your case, the only visible `\end` is that of the "second" `frame`. As such, what seems like two `frame`s in your mind is considered a single `frame` in TeX's mind. And, with an odd `\end{frame}` (the expansion of `\sld`) that doesn't have an accompanying `\begin{frame}`, TeX complains.

Comment: Note that you see the same inability to 'hide' stuff inside macros with for example AMSmath's `\begin{align}`/`\end{align}` pair for a not dissimilar reason.

Comment: Great explanation for a process that goes totally unadverted for the user and can cause a headache.