# Trying to understand \def\def@ sintax primitives

Tags: primitives

I am trying to understand this syntax of primitive `\def`

```
\DeclareOption{man}{%
\def\def@man{\@manmode}
}
```

Why this primitive nesting? And I do not get to understand why there is two `\def` sentences concatenated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally you'll see these `\DeclareOption{<opt>}{<stuff>}` declarations in style (`.sty`) and class (`.cls`) files. The allow the user to use the style/package or class with certain parameter specification which could influence the usage. In the above case, the option `man` is declared that `\def`ines `\def@man` to be `\@manmode`, or in short

```
\def\def@man{\@manmode}
```

It should also be noted that inside a `.sty` or `.cls`, the `@` character has special meaning, or TeXnically, a different [category code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16410/5764). Specifically, `@` acts like any other non-numeric letter, and can therefore form part of a macro name. That is, it makes `\def@man` a valid macro name, similar to `\@manmode`. Another way of stating the above inside a regular document would have required something like

```
\makeatletter
\def\def@man{\@manmode}
\makeatother
```

Above, [`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764) perform the same task inherent to style and class files.

Comment: Ok werner i understand, even i was testing with \def-man , \def_man , \def.man and errors occurred but \def@man ¡Work!

Comment: @AjedrezIvan: Yes. That's because `@` is special and set to being similar to other *letter*s inside a `.sty` or `.cls`. `-`, `_` and `.` are not considered *letter*s and therefore do not work out-of-the-box for macro names. It is possible to use them, but not using a straight `\def`.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways how to read `\def\def@man{...}`. If catcode of `@` is set to 11 (letter) at the time the text above is read from the file then the control sequence `def@man` is defined here.

If catcode of `@` is set to 12 (other, this is more usual) then `\def\def@man{...}` redefines the TeX primitive `\def` as a macro with mandatory separator `@man` and (probably) the next TeX processing is broken because many macros use `\def` and assume that `\def` is primitive.

Comment: Thanks wipet, however the firts paragraph of your answer It was what I was looking for