# Followup on \def@

Tags: arguments

[Trying to understand \def\def@ sintax primitives](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220426/trying-to-understand-def-def-syntax-primitives)

As a followup to this question, I'm currently working on a BA, using a set of definitions I found on a template's .cls file.  Currently:

```
% The year and term the thesis is submitted 

\def\degreedate#1{\gdef\@degreedate{#1}}

% The full (unabbreviated) name of the degree

\def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}}

% The name of your Oxford college (e.g. Christ Church, Pembroke)

\def\college#1{\gdef\@college{#1}}
```

Runs smoothly, but when I add

```
% The name of the adviser

\def\adviser#1{\gdef\@adviser{#1}}
```

It breaks with a problem with `\@argdef` apparently.

I get

Comment: Hello there, welcome to the site. The `>` markdown is for quotes, when you add code, you should use code sample markdown. The easiest way to do this is just paste the code in, highlight it all and hit the Code Sample button (the one like { }) or hit Ctrl+k. The long way is to use four spaces before each line instead of the `>`s

Comment: This doesn't show any obvious signs of being problematic. What do you get?

Comment: Is there a `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair around this `\def\def@...` stuff in your trial document?

Comment: Welcome, why the classicthesis tag?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\adviser#1{\gdef\@adviser{#1}}
\def\showadviser{My advisor is: \@adviser}
\makeatother
\adviser{Cazzolato}
\showadviser
\end{document}
```

Suggest you create an example that demonstrates your problem.