# How to typeset the percent symbol inside \detokenize?

Tags: macros, detokenize

I am writing some personal notes about R programming.
I defined a macro to typeset R functions and operators
using a different font style and color:

```
\newcommand{\rtext}[1]{%
  {\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}%
}
```

The macro is able to detokenize underscore characters `_`
so that I can easily type R functions such as `\rtext{seq_along}`.

Today I found that the macro fails at detokenizing the percent character `%`,
for example when I try to typeset the `%>%` operator
which is from the R package `magrittr`.
I understand that this is because the percent character
is used to mark the start of a comment.
Unfortunately, trying to use `\rtext{\%>\%}` gives `\%>\%` as output,
which is not what is desired.

What is the right way to define the `\rtext` macro?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\rtext}[1]{%
  {\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}%
}
\begin{document}
You can write commands in a natural order
by using the \rtext{%>%} infix operator.
\end{document}
```

Gives the error:

```
Runaway argument?
{\end {document} 
! File ended while scanning use of \rtext.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

**Edit in response to answers:**
I added the use of `\rtext` in a sentence.
Unfortunately the answers provided seem to swallow the space after the command.
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Why don't you use `\verb`?

Comment: If I were to use `\verb`, I wouldn't have the text in the color that I want, e.g. blue text in the font size `\small`.

Comment: @ILiketoCode: You could change that...

Comment: @ILikeToCode IIRC you could redefine `\verbatim@font`

Comment: This `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,xcolor}
\begin{document}
text {\color{blue}\begin{verbbox}[\small\rmfamily]
My text
\end{verbbox}
\theverbbox} text
\end{document}` will give small blue (rmfamily) verbatim font, inline. Just make sure you start the verbatim text on a new line, after closing the optional argument.

Comment: @clemens Could you submit as a short answer how to redefine `\verbatim@font`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Your method works but is quite verbose. Is there a way to put it into a command?

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is no general way to place verbatim code inside another command.

Answer (score 4):

You can do some catcode magic.  The general idea is as follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\detokenizeWithComments{%%
  \bgroup
    \catcode`\%=12
    \ae@detokenize@with@comments
  }


\def\ae@detokenize@with@comments#1{%%
    \detokenize{#1}%%
  \egroup}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

  Hello world
  \detokenizeWithComments{This has % in it}

  %% back to normal

  back to normal (shouldn't be repeated)

  %% but this next line will fail if uncommented!!!
  %%\texttt{\detokenizeWithComments{This has % in it}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To get your `\rtext` to work, you can approach it in this manner:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\rtext{%%
  \bgroup
    \catcode`\%=12
    \ae@r@text
}

\def\ae@r@text#1{%%
  \texttt{\detokenize{#1}}%%
\egroup}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

  Detokenized: \rtext{{This has % in it}}

  Back to normal

\end{document}
```

As noted by @egreg This macro will not play nicely within another macro or environment that has already read in the arguments.  This is similar to the issue with `\verb` not working nested within other macros.  The catcodes are alrady set and the `%` is already seen as a comment character before the *catcode magic* ever has a chance to take effect:  not even `\scantokens` can come to the rescue here.  And hence the fact that I couldn't just define:

```
\newcommand\rtext[1]{\texttt{\detokenizeWithComments{#1}}
```

If you try that, you'll just get the same error you originally had.

Regarding category codes, you could set the category code to `11` for letters as I originally did in this answer.  But since `\detokenize` sets the category codes to `12`, setting

```
\catcode`\%=12
```

makes an aesthetically cleaner choice.

Comment: With the note that this `\rtext` command can't be used in the argument to another command. This is unavoidable, unless we change the category code of `%` globally (to category code 12, please).

Answer (score 3):

Similar to A.Ellett's answer: Switch the [category code of `%`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16410/5764) from "comment character" to "other" and back again:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% Switch catcode for % to other
\newcommand{\rtext}{%
  \catcode`\%=12
  \@rtext}
% Switch catcode for % back to comment character
\newcommand{\@rtext}[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}\catcode`\%=14}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\rtext{%>%}
\end{document}
```

Note that one could use comment characters in the definition of `\@rtext` in order to make the macro code more readable despite the fact that you've changed the `\catcode` of `%` to be "other" (and therefore printable):

```
\newcommand{\@rtext}[1]{%
  \texttt{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \catcode`\%=14}
```

The reason for this is because the category codes are fixed at definition time, and therefore `%` still represents a comment character inside `\@rtext`.

Comment: `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` are much better. And category code 12 too.

Comment: @egreg Why category code 12?  And why `\begingroup` instead of `\bgroup`....?

Comment: @A.Ellett `\bgroup` and `\egroup` surely work. Personal preference. Category code 12 is for “other characters”. Not a big deal here, because `\detokenize` will transform everything except spaces into category code 12.

Comment: @egreg Well, that makes sense to me.  I'll change that in my answer.