# Space lost after \newcommand

Tags: spacing, macros, equations

I use the initialism "CE" a lot in my thesis, both in an out of equations. I find that the letters are too far spaced for my liking when used in an equation, so I use the `\!` command to reduce the spacing. When I do this manually it seems to work perfectly, but when I incorporate the this into a `\newcommand` the result is that I always lose a space after the command if one exists.

Is there a way to stop this? It would be even better if I could have one command in and out of equation environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

% Commands
\newcommand\CE{{C\!E}}  % CE for equation environment
\newcommand\ce{$C\!E$}  % CE for inline writing

\ce. \ce this is a line.        % space lost after second \ce

$\CE$. $\CE$ this is a line.    % Works fine but cumbersome

$C\!E$. $C\!E$ this is a line.  % Works fine but would like this in a command

\end{document}
```

[image: CE spacing image]

Comment: Since "CE" isn't the product of two variables named "C" and "E", you should use either `\newcommand\CE{\textit{CE}}` or `\newcommand\CE{\mathit{CE}}`. There will be no difference if you use the Computer Modern font family for your document, but there may be a difference if you use other fonts for text-mode and math-mode material.

Comment: Also, you can use `\ensuremath` to ensure that "CE" is typeset as math both inside and outside of math environments, meaning you can combine them into one command.

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/9632).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What does "CE" stand for?

Comment: CE stands for "Certainty Equivalent", A fixed outcome that an agent values equally to some uncertain distribution of outcomes. Useful stuff all around! I think I'm going to go with a suggestion in the comments of one of the answers in the "marked as duplicate question"
`{\command}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. In addition to Zarko's answer, macros should generally be followed by a trailing `\`, which is has a special character class that tells TeX to stop reading for more characters (it is trying to figure out the macro name). Or you could enclose it in a group like `{\ce}` or even `\ce{}`.

See
[What are category codes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16410/what-are-category-codes)

Unfortunately, the space (cat 10), although aesthetically pleasing, will always be eaten up by the TeX parser. The `{` (cat 1), `}` (cat 2), `$` (cat 3), and `\` (escape cat 0) will not. (alphabetical characters are cat 11)