# what is the difference between a macro and a control sequence?

Tags: macros, tex-core, expl3

In [*The LaTeX3 Interfaces*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) we find:

> ```
> \token_if_macro:NTF <token> {<true code>} {<false code>}
> ```
>
> Tests if the `<token>` is a TeX macro.
>
> ```
> \token_if_cs:NTF <token> {<true code>} {<false code>}
> ```
>
> Tests if the `<token>` is a control sequence.

So I asked myself: what is the difference?

Comment: Actually – I've done my homework :) – I believe I found the answer myself: a *control sequence* is every token starting with the escapechar, i.e., every token with category code 16. A *macro* is every control sequence (or active character with a definition) defined with `\def` and friends, i.e., every token where `\meaning` says “`macro:`”. If that is correct I'm happy to self-answer my question.

Comment: correct about macros, but there are no tokens with category code 16 (not really) basically every token that isn't a non-active character token is a control sequence token.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I know. I was referring to this quote from TeX by Topic: “TeX expands whatever is after `\ifcat` until two unexpandable tokens are found; these are then compared with respect to their category codes. Control sequence tokens are considered to have category code 16 […]”

Comment: BTW, is there a list of all the catcodes somewhere?  I can't find one in Knuth.

Comment: @JohnKormylo for example in section 2.3 of [TeX by Topic](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic) or here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16410/what-are-category-codes

Comment: The `\meaning` of macros starts with one of the following phrases: `macro:->` or `\long macro:->` or `\outer macro:->` or `\long\outer macro:->` .  A macro can be either a control sequence token (i.e. a control word token or a control symbol token) or an active character token. But I doubt that there is a test based on processing macro-arguments which is suitable for `\outer` macros as well.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Have a look at the table in **Chapter 7: How TeX reads what you type** of **The TeXbook** by **Donald E. Knuth**. Also have a look at **exercise 7.3** contained in that chapter.

Comment: About the remark  "*control sequence* is every token starting with the escapechar, i.e., every token with category code 16" : The category-code-16-thingie with `\ifcat`-comparison with control sequence tokens only applies to such control sequence tokens that are **not** `\let`equal to a non-active character token. E.g., with `\let\bgroup={` the category code of the control sequence token `\bgroup` will usually be 1 as the catcode of `{`usually is 1 also. Preceding `\noexpand` doesn't do anything about that as it also wouldn't do anything about that when preceding the `{`-character-token.

Comment: @UlrichDiez interesting. This means that in the sense of those tests `\bgroup` is neither a macro nor a control sequence…

Comment: Yes. Nonetheless `\bgroup` definitely is a control word token while control word tokens in turn are control sequence tokens. Besides this I am not quite sure whether `\tokencheck` is the correct name for a control sequence token that actually does not necessarily work on single tokens but actually does work on macro arguments while macro arguments might consist of several tokens or be empty as well...

Comment: @UlrichDiez I know it isn't defined to actually only grap tokens. It was and is nothing more than a superficial test for me while I was trying to understand `\token_if_macro:N(TF)` and `\token_if_cs:N(TF)`. Maybe I should delete it from the answer…

Comment: A non expandable test for control sequence tokens could be applying `\string` to the same token several times with the integer parameter `\escapechar` having different values. If the results of "stringifying" differ, then the token in question is a control sequence token. Otherwise it is not.

Comment: Preliminarily to macro- and control-sequence checks a test might be needed for finding out whether the argument consists of exactly one token. (Hint: If the argument is not empty while not starting with a catcode 1 character token while in case of the argument not starting with a space gobbling one undelimited argument from the argument yields emptiness and in case of the argument starting with a space token gobbling that space token yields emptiness, then it consists of a single token.)

Comment: No, don't delete it from the answer. Just point out that the requirement of the argument consisting of exactly one token must be fulfilled  so people intending to "borrow" your code can avoid unpredictable behaviour with "edge cases" like the argument being empty or consisting of several tokens.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### In short:

*Control sequences* are all tokens starting with the escapechar (usually `\`). There is one exception: Control sequence tokens which have been let to a non-active character token (like `\bgroup`) are *not* control sequences in the sense of `\token_if_cs:N(TF)`.

*Macros* are all control sequences or active characters defined with `\def` and friends.

Examples (in the sense of the conditionals of the question):

- `\newcommand` or `\documentclass` are both control sequences and macros,
- `\def`, `\relax`, or `\dimen@` are control sequences but not macros, and
- `~` is a macro but not a control sequence
- `\bgroup` is neither a macro nor a control sequence.

(assuming standard definitions). Undefined control sequences like `\@undefined` are no macros and active characters with no definition are neither macros nor control sequences.

#### A look at the definitions:

If we look at the definition of both conditionals we find:

1. `\token_if_cs:N(TF)`:

   ```
   \prg_new_conditional:Npnn \token_if_cs:N #1 { p , T ,  F , TF }
     {
       \if_catcode:w \exp_not:N #1 \scan_stop:
         \prg_return_true: \else: \prg_return_false: \fi:
     }
   ```

   This means every token which has the same category code as `\scan_stop:` (`\relax`) as `\if_catcode:w` (`\ifcat`) sees it. Citing [TeX by Topic](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic) that is the “special category code 16”.

   > TeX expands whatever is after `\ifcat` until two unexpandable tokens are found; these are then compared with respect to their category codes. Control sequence tokens are considered to have category code 16, which makes them all equal to each other, and unequal to all character tokens.
2. `\token_if_macro:N(TF)`:

   ```
   \use:x
     {
       \prg_new_conditional:Npnn \exp_not:N \token_if_macro:N ##1
         { p , T ,  F , TF }
         {
           \exp_not:N \exp_after:wN \exp_not:N \__token_if_macro_p:w
           \exp_not:N \token_to_meaning:N ##1 \tl_to_str:n { ma : }
             \exp_not:N \q_stop
         }
       \cs_new:Npn \exp_not:N  \__token_if_macro_p:w
         ##1 \tl_to_str:n { ma } ##2 \c_colon_str ##3 \exp_not:N \q_stop
     }
         {
           \if_int_compare:w \__str_if_eq_x:nn { #2 } { cro } = \c_zero
               \prg_return_true:
           \else:
               \prg_return_false:
           \fi:
         }
   ```

   This checks if `\meaning<token>` contains the string `macro:` (all category code 12 characters) which is true if the token has been defined with `\def` and friends.

---

#### A small test file:

*Remark: the test macro `\tokentest` below not actually grabs the first token but is defined with a standard non-delimited argument.*

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand*\cs[1]{\expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\string#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \token_check:N #1
  {
    \noindent \cs #1 ~ is~
    \token_if_macro:NF #1 { \emph {not} ~ }
    a~ macro \\
    \cs #1 ~ is~
    \token_if_cs:NF #1 { \emph {not} ~ }
    a~ control~ sequence \par
    meaning: ~ \expandafter \texttt \expandafter { \meaning #1 } \par
    \medskip
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \tokencheck {m}
  { \token_check:N #1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\a{}
\def\b#1{}
\long\def\c{}
\protected\def\d{}
\def\1{}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\subsection*{Defined with \cs\def}
\tokencheck\a
\tokencheck\b
\tokencheck\c
\tokencheck\d
\tokencheck\1
\tokencheck~

\subsection*{Undefined}
\tokencheck\@undefined

\newpage

\subsection*{Primitives}
\tokencheck\def
\tokencheck\relax
\tokencheck\fi
\tokencheck\ \relax

\subsection*{Defined with \cs\newbox, \cs\chardef, \dots} 
\tokencheck\&
\tokencheck\strutbox
\tokencheck\dimen@
\tokencheck\skip@

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer! How can I tell in plain TeX whether a certain control sequence is a macro?

Comment: @Evan Aad: `\show\mycs` will write info about the control sequence `\mycs` to the output stream. `\meaning\mycs` will write info about the control sequence `\mycs` into the typeset document.