# Latex environment to write in plain text mode

Tags: listings, verbatim, fancyvrb, url

A paragraph I am writing contains a lot symbols such as "{" or "_". To display those symbols as text instead of command, I have to write them as "\{" and "\_". Otherwise, Latex will say there are errors. However, there are so many of those symbols in my document and it would be very inconvenient to have to add a dash in front of them every single time.

An example:

```
\begin{document}

The Tadrart Acacus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acacus_Mountains) have a large variation of landscapes, from different-coloured dunes to arches, gorges, isolated rocks and deep wadis (ravines).

\end{document}
```

Refer to the wikipedia link: usually, I just copy the link from my browser and paste it into my paragraph. But due to the "_" symbol in the word "Acacus_Mountains", Latex will say there is an error and ask me to enclose it with the "$" symbol.

About the \verbatim environment: it would not work for me because:

1. It changes the font of the paragraph.
2. It does not go to a new line when reaching the margin.

To illustrate, I will enclose my paragraph with \verbatim:

```
  \begin{document}

  \begin{verbatim}

  The Tadrart Acacus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acacus_Mountains) have a 
  large variation of landscapes, from different-coloured dunes to arches, 
  gorges, isolated rocks and deep wadis (ravines).

  \end{verbatim}

  \end{document}
```

this is what my text looks like inside the \verbatim environment:
[image]

My question is: How to tell Latex that everything in a certain paragraph is to be interpreted as plain text?

Comment: `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` without any packages, or `fancyvrb` package, for example

Comment: I tried that but the environment does not keep text format (such as bold, italics, etc.) and does not automatically go to a new line when reaching the margin.

Comment: Well, you did not ask about keeping the format, did you?

Comment: How do you specify text formatting (bold, italics etc.)? E.g. if it's with something like `\textbf`, then doesn't that mean that you _don't_ want the backslash to be treated as plain text? Please add an example of what you want: a complete and minimal document, that illustrates all your problems and desired features (which characters you'd like treated as normally, and which formatting (etc.) you'd like to keep, and how you've indicated them).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR \textbf{} for bold, for example. But it would not work inside the \verbatim environment.

Comment: It's very hard to answer the question incrementally (one complication at a time) if you refuse to give a complete example. :-) For instance, if you want `\textbf{}` to work, then that means you want not only the backslash to be treated as the escape character, but the `{` and `} in `\textbf{...}` to be treated as the begin-group and end-group characters, so that the argument to `\textbf` can work. But at the same time you say you don't want `{` to be treated specially. All of these constraints are difficult to satisfy simultaneously, *especially when you don't say what they are.* :-)

Comment: you can try the `alltt`  environment or `Verbatim` from `fancyvrb` with `[commandchars=\\\{\}]`.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: For URLs there is the `url` package with its `\url` command. If you use `hyperref` (which loads `url` for you) the URL is even linked.

Comment: @moewe I am looking for a general way. Many times, the "_" symbol appears somewhere else in my paragraph.

Comment: OK. Where does the `_` appear in your document when it is not in a URL? (If you prefer your `\url`s in the same font as the rest of your docs, go with `\urlstyle{same}`.)

Comment: @moewe It can appear anywhere. For example, you can add that symbol to any word in my example.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I'm asking *why* it would appear. The underscore is not a natural feature of the English language or indeed any language I'm even remotely familiar with (Wikipedia tells me there are languages that use an underscore or a similar diacritical mark). So it is somewhat unusual if it were to appear out of the blue in your paragraphs. There are legitimate uses for `_` in URLs, where I would use the `\url` command. There are also legitimate uses if you want to write computer code, where `verbatim` and friends are useful. I just can't think of another case where it would occur.

Comment: Once again, you actually *don’t* want “everything in a certain paragraph is to be interpreted as plain text”: it seems to me that you want *the URL* to be typeset correctly.  For that, as you have already been told, the answer is to use the `url` package, or the `hyperref` package.

Comment: @moewe I added an illustration why the \verbatim would not work for me. About the "_" symbol, I sometimes need to write things like: my_matlab_code.m because Matlab naming rule does not allow space between characters.

Comment: For the code excerpts, see, for example, the `listings` package (note the final “s”), or the `fancyvrb` package.

Comment: @ASlowLearner Put only `my_matlab_code.m` in verbatim, not the complete paragraph. If you don't like the default verbatim font, it can be changed.

Comment: I added an example showing why \verbatim did not work for me.

Comment: `my_matlab_code.m` would fall under the "code" category I mentioned. `verbatim` comes in handy there as well as the https://ctan.org/pkg/listings package, or if you are feeling fancy and have Python installed https://ctan.org/pkg/minted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's my understanding of what you want, based on the question and comments:

- You'd like certain characters (the underscore `_` is one, and the brace `{` may be another but it's not clear as it contradicts the next point) to be treated in a not-special way (i.e. simply typeset that character).
- Unlike `verbatim`, you'd like certain characters to continue to be treated in a special way, as TeX does by default: for example in `\textbf{hello}` you'd like the `\` the `{` and the `}` to have their default (special) meanings.
- Unlike `verbatim`, you'd like the font to remain normal, and the typesetting too (regular paragraphs with line-breaks, etc).

If this is correct, it may help you to understand what goes on normally. As TeX reads your input, it has a certain “catcode” assigned to each character. (See the answers to [What are category codes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16410/what-are-category-codes) for more details.) Things with catcode 11 (“letter”) or catcode 12 (“other”) are simply typeset normally (specifically, they are treated as an instruction to typeset the glyph at that position in the currently loaded font), while others are treated specially.

By default, these are the characters that are treated specially:

- `\`, `{`, `}`
- `$`, `&`, `#`, `^`, `_`, `~`, `%`
- space, end-of-line, control characters

I assume that you want to continue to treat the characters in the first (and third) group specially, but treat the characters in the second group as just text (in TeX terminology, as “other” characters). This you can do by defining an environment like the following `simplechar`:

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newenvironment{simplechar}{%
   \catcode`\$=12
   \catcode`\&=12
   \catcode`\#=12
   \catcode`\^=12
   \catcode`\_=12
   \catcode`\~=12
   \catcode`\%=12
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{simplechar}
This is a paragraph with \textbf{bold} and \emph{emphasized} text, but ``special'' characters like $ & # ^ _ ~ % are treated normally, while {braces} are not, and the paragraph uses a normal font and wraps (has line breaks) at text width.
\end{simplechar}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Compare this to the output you get with something like `alltt`, which is just a bit better than `verbatim`:

[image: output with alltt]

The default behaviour of TeX/LaTeX, of having all those characters treated as special, makes certain things very convenient to type (entering math mode, subscripts and superscripts, defining macros, etc), but can be a “gotcha” for beginner users who just want to typeset text and don't want any of that yet. See similar thoughts by ConTeXt user [Aditya](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/323/aditya) on his blog: [Some thoughts on lowering the learning curve for using TeX](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/some-thoughts-on-lowering-the-learning-curve-for-using-tex-part-i/).

Comment: @ASlowLearner: If what you want is to interpret *all* characters except `\`, `{`, and `}` as “ordinary” characters, than load the `alltt` package and use the `alltt` environment it provides.

Comment: @GuM `alltt` doesn't do the same thing, for several reasons: (1) it switches the font to a monospaced one, (2) it doesn't typeset normal paragraphs, with line-breaking and respecting the current value of parskip and all that. (3) It doesn't cover the character `%` but this is a minor point and it's not clear whether the OP wants this anyway. In fact, if you look at the (short) implementation of the `alltt` package, almost everything it does is undesirable for the OP's use-case.

Comment: You are right, mine was a stupid comment; I will *not* delete it, however, because I think that my foolishness may actually help other users *not* to make the same error as I did. :-)

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is exactly what I thought I would want, but now I just realized that it is not a very good idea since we rarely have a paragraph with only plain text, and changing the behavior of special characters is not worth the hassle. However, I just learned a whole lot more about Latex from your answer.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\def\zzz{%
   \catcode`\$=12
   \catcode`\&=12
   \catcode`\#=12
   \catcode`\^=12
   \catcode`\_=12
   \catcode`\~=12
   \catcode`\%=12
   \catcode`\\=12 
   \catcode`\{=12
   \catcode`\}=12
   \zzzz}
{
\catcode`\/=0
\catcode`\[=1
\catcode`\]=2
\catcode`\{=12
\catcode`\}=12
\catcode`\\=12
/long/gdef/zzzz#1\end{zzz}[%
#1/end[zzz]]
]


\begin{document}

\begin{zzz}
The Tadrart Acacus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acacus_Mountains) have a large variation of landscapes, from different-coloured dunes to arches, gorges, isolated rocks and deep wadis (ravines).

and \ and & and # and } and {  not forgetting _ and ^ and %


\end{zzz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, really cool trick for the braces! But the OP seems to also want `\textbf{stuff}` to work (result in bold stuff), so it's not clear (even to the OP) exactly what is desired with the braces.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR does (s)he? the question says `{` should act like `\{`  (and I couldn't follow all the comments:-)

Comment: Yes it's hard to follow :-) The second comment said “text format (such as bold, italics, etc.)”, and the fifth comment said “\textbf{} for bold”… basically I think the OP want(ed) something impossible: for both `\textbf{...}` to work, and for the braces to act like `{`. (Well it's probably not literally impossible, e.g. a LuaTeX filter or something that looks for space followed by `}` may work, but at least it's not clear.)

Answer (score 3):

If the `url` package is loaded (preferably with the options `hyphens`, `spaces`, and `obeyspaces`) and the directive `\urlstyle{same}` is run, it's possible to encase entire paragraphs in `\url` directives. I wouldn't recommend it, though, as you'll lose hyphenation capabilities. For sure, if this were my document, I would apply `\url` directives only where necessary.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\begin{document}

\noindent
The Tadrart Acacus (\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acacus_Mountains}) have a large 
variation of landscapes, from different-coloured dunes to arches, gorges, isolated rocks 
and deep wadis (ravines), along with several \url{my_matlab_code.m} files.

\smallskip\noindent
\url{The Tadrart Acacus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acacus_Mountains) have a large 
variation of landscapes, from different-coloured dunes to arches, gorges, isolated rocks 
and deep wadis (ravines), as well as a few my_matlab_code.m files.}

\end{document}
```