# How I can make the "^", "." and "_" characters lose their meaning and rendered as normal text on truetype fonts

Tags: xetex

Hello sometime in a text like that:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\setmainfont{Liberation Serif} 
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{Arial}
\setmainfont[Kerning=On,Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}

\title{Tο μικρό γλυκό πρωτόκολλο WPA-PSK}
\date{}
\author{Τσακ Νόρις}

\begin{document}

   \maketitle

   \chapter{Επίθεση σε οικιακό δίκτυο Wi-Fi που χρησιμοποιεί WPA2-CCMP-PSK}
   \section{Εργαλεία Επίθεσης}
   Προκειμένου να εκτελεστεί η επίθεση, χρησιμοποιήσαμε το εργαλείο \texttt{airchack-ng} σε \texttt{Kubuntu Linux 16.04 lts}. Λαλαλαλα θα τα σπάσω όλα. Για να γίνει πρέπει να αντικαταστήσετε το \texttt{\^NETWORK\_BSSID\^} με το BSSID του δικτύου σας στην εντολή \texttt{i\_crack\_them\_all}.
\end{document}
```

Usually I use the marking `^SOME_DUMMY_PARAMETER^` to use as parameter fill ins when I put commands into documentation. But is rendered like that [image: bssid render]. I would like to be able to render it in a form `^BSSID^` do you know how I sould do that?

Comment: you can input as `\string^BSS\string_ID\string^` but check the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427008/4686)

Comment: @campa I don't see that they're asking for different things. The title asks for `^` and `_` to lose any special meaning (as they have in LaTeX by default) and be rendered as normal characters from the font. The body asks for the same: to be able to type `^SOME_DUMMY_PARAMETER` rather than `\_` and `\^` (or `\textasciicircum` or `\string^` or whatever).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally `^` and `_` are used for superscripts are subscripts (in mathematics). If you're typing a document without mathematics, or if you don't need any mathematics (or at least superscripts and subscripts) in a certain region of your document, then you can put:

```
\catcode`\_=12
\catcode`\^=12
```

(Put it within `\begingroup` ... `\endgroup` if you want to restrict the scope.) For your example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{Arial}
\setmainfont[Kerning=On,Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}

\title{Tο μικρό γλυκό πρωτόκολλο WPA-PSK}
\date{}
\author{Τσακ Νόρις}

\catcode`\_=12
\catcode`\^=12

\begin{document}

   \maketitle

   \chapter{Επίθεση σε οικιακό δίκτυο Wi-Fi που χρησιμοποιεί WPA2-CCMP-PSK}
   \section{Εργαλεία Επίθεσης}
   Προκειμένου να εκτελεστεί η επίθεση, χρησιμοποιήσαμε το εργαλείο \texttt{airchack-ng} σε \texttt{Kubuntu Linux 16.04 lts}. Λαλαλαλα θα τα σπάσω όλα. Για να γίνει πρέπει να αντικαταστήσετε το \texttt{^NETWORK_BSSID^} με το BSSID του δικτύου σας στην εντολή \texttt{i_crack_them_all}.
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: output]

(See [related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422197/latex-environment-to-write-in-plain-text-mode/422207#422207) for more: you may prefer to restrict this behaviour to an environment.)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, replacing `\^` with `\textasciicircum` gives the effect you want. Note that I had to comment out the lines referring to the 'Arial' font, as I don't have it.