# Are ^ and _ the only commands in LaTeX not preceded by a backslash?

Tags: math-mode, macros, subscripts, superscripts, syntax

Almost all commands in LaTeX are preceded by a backslash. Are the superscript and subscript commands in the math environment (^ and _ respectively) the only exceptions?

Comment: They are not commands, they have a special catcodes like $%\{}

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In TeX and LaTeX, it is vital to distinguish between "commands" or "control sequences" on the one hand and TeX-special characters on the other. Only the former begin, in general, with a backslash (`\`) character. (But see the final paragraph below for examples of commands which do not start with a backslash.)

`^` and `_` are but two examples of TeX-special characters. Others are `\` (backslash), `{`, `}`, `$` ("math shift"), `&`, `#`, and `%` (comment char.). What makes these characters "special" from the point of view of TeX and LaTeX is that they each have a specific special *category code*, or catcode for short. Various rules apply if one needs to typeset one of the special-catcode characters. For instance, to typeset an ampersand, hashtag, or percent character, one must prefix a backslash character to the corresponding symbol, i.e., input it as `\&`, `\#` and `\%`, respectively. To typeset the backslash symbol in text mode, one must input it as either "`\textbackslash`" or "`\string\`". (The latter method also requires the `T1` font encoding -- it doesn't work with `OT1`. With the latter method, a space after `\string\` is required if the objective is to generate a single backslash character; a likely undesirable side effect is that a space will be output after the backslash character. In contrast, inputting, say, `\string\hello` creates `\hello`, without a space.) In math mode, one outputs a backslash character by typing either `\backslash` or `\setminus`, depending on the intended meaning: the math status of `\backslash` is "ord" (ordinary), whereas that of `\setminus` is "bin" (binary).

If there are "special" catcodes, there must also be "non-special" catcodes, right? This is indeed the case. The main non-special catcodes are reserved for *letters* (e.g., `a` to `z` and `A` to `Z`), *space characters*, and *"other" characters* (such as numerals, punctuation marks, apostrophes, `"`, `@`, `(`, `)`, `-` and `/`). Characters with non-special catcodes can be entered directly, i.e., they don't need to be prefixed with anything special. End-of-line, "ignored", and "invalid" characters are also identified by non-special catcodes.

Finally, there is a catcode for *active characters*. An "active" character is an example of a command which does *not* start with a backslash. In most TeX installations, the catcode of `~` ("tilde") is "active"; the main use of `~` is to insert an unbreakable space between two words. To typeset a tilde character directly, it is necessary to input it as `\~{}` in text mode and as `\tilde{}` in math mode. AFAICT, thouth, stand-alone tildes are rather uncommon in general typographic applications. (Typesetting URL strings is a specialized application, I suppose.) The tilde character occurs frequently as a diacritic or "accent symbol", e.g., `\~n` in `Espa\~na` and `$\tilde{z}$`. Another example: If the `babel` package is loaded with the option `french`, the catcodes of certain punctuation marks, such as `:` and `;`, are changed from "other" to "active". This change facilitates the implementation of French typographic practices for these punctuation marks.

Comment: (+1) Maybe you could mention numerals, too?

Comment: The tilde is also rather common in url's, where it causes problems unless properly handled (often by the `url` package).  `&`, `#`, and `%` can be present in url's as well (I'm not certain that I'm not forgetting something) and must also be dealt with specially for that use.

Comment: @cfr - Thanks for the suggestion! I'll add them into the answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Indeed, the proper way to deal with TeX-special and active characters that occur inside URL strings is to (a) load the `url` or, better still, the `xurl` package and (b) encase the URL strings in `\url` directives. (The catcodes of all characters in the argument of `\url` are changed to "other", obviating the need to prefix them with, say, backslash characters.) It's definitely *not a good idea* to change instances of `~`, `_`, `%`, and `#` in URL strings to `\~`, `\_`, etc., as doing so will make the URL strings unusable if the `hyperref` package is loaded as well.

Comment: ``\string\`` is actually `\string\␣`, so you get a space after the backslash, which might not be desirable. Perhaps `\@backslashchar` (which is defined as `\edef\@backslashchar\expandafter\@gobble\string\\}`).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik - Thanks for this. I've updated the answer to mention the potential issue of an unwanted space.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an answer from the perspective of the internals of the TeX (to be specific, Knuth TeX) program. You **do not need to know** any of the following for simply using TeX; this is just if you're curious about how things work internally.

### Stomach “commands”

The "main" part of the TeX program (after some initialization etc) is basically a [main loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Event_loop&oldid=921599892) (called `main_control` in the source code). The structure of the code is somewhat like the following pseudocode:

```py
def main_control():
    while True:
        get_x_token  # Sets `cur_cmd` and `cur_chr`.
        # Now perform some action based on `mode` and `cur_cmd`...
        # ... this action may use the value of `cur_chr`.
```

This main control routine is what Knuth describes in the manual (*The TeXbook*) as the “stomach” of TeX: it hungrily waits for tokens (commands, and details thereof), which are delivered to it from the “mouth” of TeX (above, `get_x_token`).

So from the perspective of the guts of TeX, *everything* that reaches it is a command: for instance the letter “e” is delivered to the stomach as the command “letter” (with `cur_chr` = 101). For this “letter” command, the corresponding action (if TeX is in horizontal mode) is simply “append this character to the current hlist in the current font”.

Here are some common “commands” (with their—mostly irrelevant—internal codes), in what cases TeX's stomach gets those commands, and the corresponding action that is taken:

- **letter** (11): TeX's stomach gets this command when you type a character regarded as a letter (by default: A..Z, a..z). The action (when in horizontal mode) is to append that character to the current hlist.
- **other_char** (12): TeX's stomach gets this command when you type a character like (by default) `"'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@[]|` or the backtick. The action (when in horizontal mode) is to append that character to the current hlist.
- **spacer** (10): TeX's stomach gets this command when you type a character like space (ASCII 32) or tab (ASCII 9). The action is to append the normal inter-word glue or a larger glue, depending on space_factor (etc).
- **hskip** (26): TeX's stomach gets this command when you type `\hskip` or `\hfil` or something like that. The action is to scan (if necessary) and then append the corresponding glue.
- **assign_int** (73): TeX's stomach gets this command when you type certain commands like `\tolerance` or `\day`. The action is to call an internal procedure called `prefixed_command` (which in this case will scan a value for the corresponding integer and assign that value).
- **def** (97): TeX's stomach gets this command when you type `\def` or `\edef` or `\xdef` or `\gdef`. The action is to call an internal procedure called `prefixed_command` (which in this case will scan a control-sequence name, then parameters, then a definition token list, and assign that meaning).
- **left_brace** (1) (begin group): TeX's stomach gets this command when you type (by default) `{`. The action is to start a new save level.
- **math_shift** (3): TeX's stomach gets this command when you type (by default) `$`. The action is to enter or appropriately exit math mode.
- **sup_mark** (7): TeX's stomach gets this command when you type (by default) `^`. The action if not in math mode is to print an error and `insert_dollar_sign` (as error recovery), and if in math mode is to call `sub_sup` (which handles subscripts and superscripts).
- **par_end** (13): TeX's stomach gets this command at the end of each paragraph (`\par` or a blank line).
- **extension** (59): left for extensions to TeX, including some built-in features of TeX that are implemented *like* extensions just to illustrate. The action is to call `do_extension`.
- **out_param** (5) (output a parameter): TeX's stomach gets this command when it encounters, in a token list, whatever it had put there when you typed `#1` or ... or `#9`.
- **relax** (0): TeX's stomach may get this command when you type `\relax`. The action is to do nothing.

There are about 100 commands that can reach TeX's stomach; TeX extensions like eTeX, pdfTeX, XeTeX or LuaTeX have more. Some of them, like “letter”, occur so frequently that TeX considers part of the “main loop” that is more heavily optimized.

### Mouth “commands”

All this was about TeX's “stomach” (the main control loop and semantic routines / action procedures). But TeX's “mouth” (scanning routines) is no less interesting. There's a lot that goes on there, before it delivers a command to the stomach.

Note that in the above, I said that some of these commands were triggered by a single character of input, and also the frequent remarks of “by default”. This is because TeX has a concept of **category codes**. There are 16 of them and you can read details on page 37 of *The TeXbook* or many questions on this site, e.g. [What are category codes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16410/what-are-category-codes). I won't repeat all that, but just some examples:

- When TeX's mouth sees a character with catcode 11 (letter), it sends the command “letter” (also 11) to the stomach.
- When TeX's mouth sees a character with catcode 12 (other character), it sends the command “other_char” (also 12) to the stomach.
- When TeX's mouth sees a character with catcode 1 (beginning of group), it sends the command “left_brace” (also 1) to the stomach.

Similarly for catcode 2 (end of group/“right_brace”), catcode 3 (math shift/“math_shift”), catcode 4 (alignment tab/“tab_mark”), catcode 7 (superscript/“sub_mark”), catcode 8 (subscript/“sub_mark”), catcode 10 (space/“spacer”), which includes the `^` and `_` mentioned in the question.

But!

- When TeX's mouth sees a character with catcode 14 (comment, like `%` by default), it doesn't immediately send anything to the stomach but simply skips to the end of the line -- it will send a command when it encounters a real one.
- When TeX's mouth sees a character with catcode 13 (active character, like `~` by default), it looks up the meaning of that active character and correspondingly does a macro call or expansion or whatever.
- When TeX's mouth sees a character with catcode 0 (escape character, like the backslash by default), it scans for a control sequence (basically, either a single nonletter or a sequence of letters), then looks up that control sequence in a hash table to find out its meaning, then either says “undefined control sequence” or expands it or...

A lot can happen in the mouth, e.g. conditionals like `\if`, or macro calls (anything that was defined with `\def` or similar), or opening a file with `\input`, or things like `\expandafter`. Only when all this “chewing” is done and there's a “real” command does one reach the stomach.

### Summary

From a *user* perspective, TeX has

- “commands” like `\hskip` or `\llap`,
- active characters like `~` (which too may be called commands),
- special-catcode characters like `$` or `^` or `_` (which are not usually called commands), and
- common-catcode (“letter” or “other char”) characters like `e` or `5` (which are almost never called commands).

From an *internal* perspective,

- characters have catcodes,
- based on which the mouth may do further scanning or expansion (in the case of a backslash or active characters like `~`),
- and continue to do expansion based on what it got (like `\llap` is a macro that expands to `\hbox to\z@{\hss#1}`),
- and finally delivers commands to the stomach (e.g. `\llap` results in a `make_box` command delivered),
- these “commands” include not only things like “hskip” (which correspond to what you as a user may consider a command `\hskip`), but also things like “math_shift” and “sup_mark” and even “other_char” and “letter” (often made from a single character of input),
- but these “commands” do *not* include things like `\input` or `\if` or `\string` that you may consider a command.

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX can print which characters have a non-literal meaning:

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\do#1{\ifnum\catcode\string`#1=12 \else
\message{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}\fi}
\typeout{}\message{Chars:}%
\do\!\do\"\do\#\do\$\do\%\do\&\do\'\do\(\do\)\do\*\do\+\do\,%
\do\-\do\.\do\/\do\:\do\;\do\<\do\=\do\>\do\?\do\@\do\[\do\\%
\do\]\do\^\do\_\do\`\do\{\do\|\do\}\do\~%
\typeout{}%
\@@end
```

It prints:

```
Chars: # $ % & @ \ ^ _ { } ~
```

If we rerun it with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}
```

prepended, it prints more:

```
Chars: ! # $ % & : ; ? @ \ ^ _ { } ~
```

I tried this (and it works) in TeX Live 2015 and 2018, with *latex*, *pdflatex* and *lualatex*.

Comment: When I adapt your example code to run under pdfLaTeX, the only characters that get printed out, whether or not the `babel` package is loaded with the option `french`, are `#`, `%`, and `&`. Apparently, I didn't do the adaptation properly. Would you mind editing your answer so that the code is compilable without any guesswork?

Comment: `pdflatex` and `latex` should produce the same console output. For the commands in TeX Live 2015, they do for me.

Comment: Your code doesn't run *as is* under TeXLive2019, at least not without some important adaptation. If it's necessary to run your code under TeXLive2015, you should say so up front.

Comment: pdflatex and latex should produce the same console output. For the commands in TeX Live 2015 and 2018, they do for me.

Comment: @Mico: There is no need to adapt my code for pdfLaTeX, you should run it as is. This code has been working in the last >20 years both in `latex` and `pdflatex`. It sounds unlikely that `pdflatex` in TeX Live 2019 started behaving differently, and also it's highly unusual and very-very-very weird that only `#`, `%` and `&` are non literal, TeX couldn't possibly work that way. However, I don't have TeX Live 2019 installed, and I won't install it just because of this. (Is there any online LaTeX envirnoment I can try?) I've updated the answer with info on which TeX Live version worked for me.