# Using string to process a macro name using listofitems seems to fail

Tags: macros, strings, xstring, parsing

I am trying to process the name of a command using `listofitems`, but when I am using `\string` to convert that command it does not behave the way I think it would behave.

Here is a code to illustrate:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\makeatletter\newcommand{\currentname}{}

% Process ABC@DEF
\newcommand{\makelistA}[1]{
    \setsepchar{@}%
    \renewcommand{\currentname}{#1}%
    \readlist\currentlist{\currentname}%
    \currentname = [\currentlist[1],\currentlist[2]]\newline%
}
\newcommand{\runA}{\makelistA{ABC@DEF}}

% Process the command \ABC@DEF
\newcommand{\ABC@DEF}{}
\newcommand{\makelistB}[1]{
    \setsepchar{@}%
    \renewcommand{\currentname}{\StrGobbleLeft{\string#1}{1}}%
    \readlist\currentlist{\currentname}%
    \currentname = [\currentlist[1],\currentlist[2]]\newline%
}
\newcommand{\runB}{\makelistB{\ABC@DEF}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\runA % Writes ABC@DEF = [ABC,DEF] as expected
\runB % Writes ABC@DEF = [ABC@DEF,ABC@DEF] and generates errors
\end{document}
```

The version that process the command fails, and I cannot understand why.

Any explanation? And how to make it work?

Comment: `\string` is only used to write macros without expanding them, usually to the aux file.  I believe what you want is `\detokenize`.

Comment: How do you use that in this specific example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems. First and foremost,

```
\renewcommand{\currentname}{\StrGobbleLeft{\string#1}{1}}
```

is never going to work, because `\StrGobbleLeft` is not expandable. You want

```
\StrGobbleLeft{\string#1}{1}[\currentname]
```

which would correctly store `ABC@DEF` in `\currentname`. However, `listofitems` won't find `@`, because you're defining the command in a context where `@` has category code 11, but in the generated string it has category code 12.

You may want

```
\newcommand{\makelistB}[1]{%
    \expandafter\setsepchar\expandafter{\string @}%
    \StrGobbleLeft{\string#1}{1}[\currentname]%
    \readlist\currentlist{\currentname}%
    \currentname = [\currentlist[1],\currentlist[2]]\newline
}
```

so the separator `@` certainly has category code 12.

Here's the `expl3` code that's not confused by category codes.

```
\documentclass{article}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makelist}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \cs_to_str:N #1 }
  \regex_split:nVN { \@ } \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_seq
  [\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {,}]
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_split:nnN { nV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\makeatletter % pretend we're in a package file

\newcommand{\ABC@DEF}

\makelist{\ABC@DEF}

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

The output, as you can check, is

> [ABC,DEF]

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with the code. The first is that storing the output of `xstring` macros should not be done with `\renewcommand`. This stores the whole code of `\StrGobbleLeft` in the command, while you only want the result. With `xstring` this is done with an optional final argument:

```
\StrGobbleLeft{\string#1}{1}[\currentname]
```

The second issue is a catcode problem. You use `\makeatletter`, which sets the category code of `@` to 11 (i.e., letters, see [What are category codes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16410/what-are-category-codes)). However, `\string` (and `\detokenize` as well) set the category code of `@` to 12 (i.e., other). Now `listofitems` cannot split the list because it is looking for a separator with catcode 11 while you provide a separator with catcode 12, and token comparison is catcode-aware.

The solution is easy: don't make at letter, but make it other.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\currentname}{}

% Process ABC@DEF
\newcommand{\makelistA}[1]{
    \setsepchar{@}%
    \renewcommand{\currentname}{#1}%
    \readlist\currentlist{\currentname}%
    \currentname = [\currentlist[1],\currentlist[2]]\newline%
}
\newcommand{\runA}{\makelistA{ABC@DEF}}

% Process the command \ABC@DEF
\newcommand{\ABC@DEF}{}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\makelistB}[1]{
    \setsepchar{@}%
    \StrGobbleLeft{\string#1}{1}[\currentname]
    \readlist\currentlist{\currentname}%
    \currentname = [\currentlist[1],\currentlist[2]]\newline%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\runB}{\makelistB{\ABC@DEF}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\runA % Writes ABC@DEF = [ABC,DEF] as expected
\runB % Same output as above
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the catcode change must be done *outside* of `\newcommand{\makelistB}` to make the change effective during the definition of the command instead of during execution, which is too late as the `@` symbols are already tokenized at that point.

---

A possible improvement to `listofitems` would be do make the separator comparison catcode-independent, similar to `xstring` which offers starred variants like `\IfStrEq*` that first normalizes catcodes and then perform the comparison.