# pgfkeys' first char syntax detection failure

Tags: pgfkeys

I saved the following code in the file `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{
   /handlers/first char syntax=true,
   /handlers/first char syntax/the character a/.initial=\LowercaseA
}
\def\LowercaseA#1{#1}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{aardvark}
\end{document}
```

The code configures the `\pgfkeys` command to inspect the first character of each key, and if this character is the letter `a`, to call the `\LowercaseA` command with a single argument: the key. The `\LowercaseA` command simply expands to its argument. The code then calls `\pgfkeys`, passing it the key `aardvark`.

Then I executed the following commands in the Terminal.

```
> cd ~
> pdflatex Test
```

The compilation failed, and `~/Test.log` contained the following error message.

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/aardvark' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \pgfkeys{aardvark}
```

This came as an undesirable surprise. I expected the compilation to succeed, and for the PDF file to display the string "aardvark". My expectations were based on the following quote from section 87.3.1 *First Char Syntax Detection* of the *PGF & TikZ* manual for version 3.1.9a (the current version), on p. 977:

> Usually, keys are of the form `〈key〉=〈value〉` and how such keys are handled is discussed in the rest of this section. However, it is also possible to setup a different syntax for certain parts of the input to `\pgfkeys`. [...] this special syntax detection is the very first thing that is done when a key is processed, before any of the following operations are performed.

**Questions**

1. Why did the compilation fail?
2. How can I change my code so that the generated PDF file displays the string "aardvark"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check `\meaning a` it's catcode 11 letter so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{
   /handlers/first char syntax=true,
   /handlers/first char syntax/the letter a/.initial=\LowercaseA
}
\def\LowercaseA#1{#1}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{aardvark}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oof, I can't believe I made this silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: I realize why I made this mistake. In my real life code (as opposed to the minimal working example that I listed in my original post) I use as first letter flags for `pgfkeys` not only alphabetical letters but also digits, and the `\meaning` of digits starts with `the character` (as opposed to `the letter`), so I assumed this applied to letters as well, and simply copied-and-pasted without verifying with the `\meaning` command.

Comment: @EvanAad digits are catcode 12

Answer (score 3):

It needs to be

```
/handlers/first char syntax/the letter a/.initial=\LowercaseA
```

The [manual states](https://tikz.dev/pgfkeys#handlers/first:char:syntax/meta(meaning:of:character))

> The `<meaning of character>` should be the text that TeX’s command `\meaning` returns […].

Since `a` is a letter ([catcode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16410/16595) 11) and not a character (catcode 12, *other*), this is `the letter a`.

You can check this yourself with – as the manual states –

```
\meaning a
```

or, if you want to just let TeX do the work, just do

```
/handlers/first char syntax/\meaning a/.initial=\LowercaseA
```

in the first place.

Of course, your code won't work anymore if the catcode of `a` changes but if it does you've got bigger problems …

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{
   /handlers/first char syntax=true,
%   /handlers/first char syntax/\meaning a/.initial=\LowercaseA,
   /handlers/first char syntax/the letter a/.initial=\LowercaseA,
}
\def\LowercaseA#1{#1}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{aardvark}

%\begingroup % This will fail because a is no longer a letter
%  \catcode`\a=12
%  \pgfkeys{aardvark}
%\endgroup

\end{document}
```