Print \twocolumn and \onecolumn
How can I print \twocolumn and \onecolumn because \\ makes a new line.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand {\lumnar} {}
  {
    \\twocolumn~and~\\onecolumn~always~start~a~new~page.

    They~are~useful~for~a~one~column~appendix~in~a~two~column~paper,~or
    a~two~column~index~in~a~one~column~paper.

  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lumnar

\end{document}


\texttt{\string\twocolumn}, but why are you complicating life with \ExplSyntaxOn in this context?

Is using \c_backslash_str still a good answer ?  How can I include a string just after so I get  \twocolumn to be printed ?

\c_backslash_str{}twocolumn~and~\c_backslash_str{}onecolumn will works.

Haven't we decided to use \c_backslash_str ?

What is catcode 12 ?

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16410/what-are-category-codes

Some special characters can be printed as themselves by escaping them:
\{ \} \$ \& \# \_ \%

Others can't:
\ ^ ~

The combination \\ is used in many places to denote “go to a new line” (but it should not be used in normal text, only in environments where it makes sense to do it). The combinations \^ and \~ produce accents.
Why didn't Knuth (and Lamport) define \\, \^ and \~ to produce the special character as printable? Because they don't appear in most printed documents.
Of course, if one wants to speak about TeX, the characters are needed, but there's usually verbatim mode.
If you need to insert control sequence names in your document, using verbatim is not necessary, though. Just do
\newcommand{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\symbol{`\\}#1}}

and you can type \cs{onecolumn} to get \onecolumn in output. The concoction
\symbol{`\\}

means “print the glyph in the current font taking the slot corresponding to the ASCII code of the backslash” and is equivalent to \symbol{92}, but doesn't require to look up in the table of ASCII codes. Note that if you don't use T1 encoding, \texttt is necessary, because OT1 encoded fonts usually don't have a backslash in slot 92.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\symbol{`\\}onecolumn\qquad \texttt{\symbol{`\\}onecolumn}

\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont

\symbol{`\\}onecolumn\qquad \texttt{\symbol{`\\}onecolumn}

\end{document}


Using \texttt is customary for printing TeX code and your readers will better distinguish it from the context.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\cs}{m}{\texttt{\symbol{`\\}#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand {\lumnar} {}{%
  \cs{twocolumn} and \cs{onecolumn} always start a new page.
  They are useful for a one column appendix in a two column paper, or
  a two column index in a one column paper.}

\begin{document}

\lumnar

\end{document}


I don't see any advantage in using expl3-style coding for such a job. Note that even using \c_backslash_str wouldn't free you from the need of using \texttt or, at least, T1 encoding.
You may use expl3 for a different purpose, namely the ability of typing either \cs{onecolumn} or \cs{\onecolumn}`.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\cs}{m}{\texttt{\franklin_cs:n {#1}}}

\cs_new:Nn \franklin_cs:n
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \str_head:n { #1 } } { \c_backslash_str }
   { \token_to_str:N #1 }  % argument has a backslash
   { \c_backslash_str #1 } % argument hasn't a backslash
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand {\lumnar} {}{%
  \cs{twocolumn} and \cs{\onecolumn} always start a new page.
  They are useful for a one column appendix in a two column paper, or
  a two column index in a one column paper.}

\begin{document}

\lumnar

\end{document}

