# Obfuscating TeX

Tags: tex-core, fun

Given TeX's system of catcodes, I imagine that one can [obfuscate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code) TeX to a remarkable degree. With a view to learning more about the internals of TeX, I ask: How might I go about adding a block of obfuscated code to my document? Let's say I want to add a watermark to my document that I don't want my co-author to be able to edit. How might I do that?

What tricks can I use to make a certain piece of code harder to understand?

Comment: See also [Can I see a plain TeX source file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6490/2693) whose answers quickly morphed into obfuscation.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/can-you-explain-how-this-code-works

Comment: “There is an annual obfuscated C programming contest. The same would be rather pointless for TeX: every nontrivial task has only obfuscated solutions, anyway.” – http://www.tug.org/interviews/kastrup.html

Comment: are you using XeTeX? It allows a much larger range of characters, and that might be used to store several Latin characters per character.

Comment: And what happens if your co-author just remove the lines of obfuscated code?

Comment: Another nice one: http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/texhax/2011-March/017021.html (or, seems to be better found by searching engines: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.texhax/15416).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try out [xii.tex](http://ctan.org/pkg/xii). It's a plainTeX file, you can find it on CTAN.

And Enrico “[egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427)” Gregorio produced a similar code, even shorter. See in [What is the most bizarre thing you have seen done with TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156937), where it is called `xcix.tex`.

Comment: Wow, that is pretty impressive. In comparison, obfuscated C reads like a newspaper :-)

Comment: There's also [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) which is obfuscated almost by design.

Comment: How is this even possible? The input file contains 766 characters, the output document about thrice that number‽ Is there a package used containing the lyrics? Also: Brainfuck ... we meet again.

Comment: @doncherry: If you look at the answers to the question Yiannis has linked to (comment on the question) then you will see how to analyse `xii.tex`. It is most enlightening: `\tracingall` is your friend here :-)

Comment: 'Tis wicked! *Wicked*, I say!

Comment: @Alan: I don't find Brainfuck all that hard to read, I have to say.  You shift cells left and right, increment or decrement their contents, and input/output their contents as characters - only the looping construct holds any slight mystery.  Tedious, verbose, encoding intense, but not really hard to figure out.  Tex is much more interesting.  I haven't see obfuscated Tex that really got to grips with the joys of  `\let\\\loop\let\|\ifx\let\/\repeat`, say.

Comment: @CharlesStewart Since `\loop` is a delimited macro, the redefinition you make wouldn't work: `\\` would not see the `\repeat` that it expects.  [`reverxii.tex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/contrib/reverxii) gives an example of obfuscated recursive code.

Comment: @Bruna: Quite so, my comment was a little thoughtless - we need `\def`s, not `\let`s, to get this to work.  reverxii would be an excellent answer - it is possible to understand the techniques (e.g., iterative definitions, choice of Tex primitives) by looking at the code - would you care to post?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using XeTeX, here is some (slightly obfuscated) code to pack (`\p`) pairs of Ascii characters into one Unicode character, storing the result in `\toks0` (token register, which I called `\|` below), or unpack (`\u`) the result.

The encoding uses the fact that visible ascii characters have a character code (acessed with `` \number` ``) between `32` (space) and `127` (tilde), so they can be stored in two digits by shifting by `32`. Four digits are then packed in one character by adding `10000` (minus the two shifts of `32`, hence `6768`, minus a `32` hidden in the definition of `\.`, hence `6736`), to ensure that this gives 5 digits (starting with 1).

Decoding reads characters one at a time, through `` \number` ``, which gives `1`, followed by two pairs of digits. We add `32` to each pair, set the uppercase code of `.` to that value, and store `\uppercase{.}` in `\|`.

Stopping the loop is done by inserting `\iffalse` at the right place in both packing and unpacking.

```
% Packing 2 ascii char per Unicode char with XeTeX.
\begingroup
\toksdef\|0
\let\ea\expandafter
\def\>{\uppercase{\|\ea{\the\|.}}}
\def\.{\uccode`.\numexpr32+}
\def\p#1{\|{}\ea\q#1\ {\ \iffalse}\ \fi\relax}
\def\q#1#2{\.\number`#100+`#2+6736\>\q}
\def\u#1{\|{}\ea\v\number`#1 \^^J{\iffalse}..\fi\relax}
\def\v1#1#2#3#4{\.#1#2\>\.#3#4\>\ea\v\number`}
% Example
\p{The\ main\ author\ is\ Seamus!}\showthe\|
\ea\u\ea{\the\|}\showthe\|
\endgroup
\csname @@end\endcsname\end
```

The group is there to avoid leaking out the definitions. Of course, you probably want to only leave the definitions for `\u`, and write `\u{㮨䈄䃉䠨䘾❙䝼㭁䃁䢗❴}\message{\the\|}` in your document.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found `\char` and so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\char'110 \char'105 \char'114 \char'114 \char'117 \kern .8em \char'127 \char'117\char'122 \char'114 \char'104
\end{document}
```

Also, I wonder if there's a way to access what your document looks like after it's all been expanded down to primitives. I think that would in itself be pretty obfuscated...

Comment: As gets pointed out a lot, TeX does not expand to primitives independent of typesetting. The nearest you can get is `\tracingall`.

Comment: @Joseph well, what I meant was, I wonder if there's a way to see what the output would look like if you expanded a whole bunch of the macros (but perhaps not all of them)...