# How could the macro xii.tex be simplified into a better readable form

Tags: macros, tex-core

I was reading some TeX guides from where I have found this source:

```
\let~\catcode~`76~`A13~`F1~`j00~`P2jdefA71F~`7113jdefPALLF
PA''FwPA;;FPAZZFLaLPA//71F71iPAHHFLPAzzFenPASSFthP;A$$FevP
A@@FfPARR717273F737271P;ADDFRgniPAWW71FPATTFvePA**FstRsamP
AGGFRruoPAqq71.72.F717271PAYY7172F727171PA??Fi*LmPA&&71jfi
Fjfi71PAVVFjbigskipRPWGAUU71727374 75,76Fjpar71727375Djifx
:76jelse&U76jfiPLAKK7172F71l7271PAXX71FVLnOSeL71SLRyadR@oL
RrhC?yLRurtKFeLPFovPgaTLtReRomL;PABB71 72,73:Fjif.73.jelse
B73:jfiXF71PU71 72,73:PWs;AMM71F71diPAJJFRdriPAQQFRsreLPAI
I71Fo71dPA!!FRgiePBt'el@ lTLqdrYmu.Q.,Ke;vz vzLqpip.Q.,tz;
;Lql.IrsZ.eap,qn.i. i.eLlMaesLdRcna,;!;h htLqm.MRasZ.ilk,%
s$;z zLqs'.ansZ.Ymi,/sx ;LYegseZRyal,@i;@ TLRlogdLrDsW,@;G
LcYlaDLbJsW,SWXJW ree @rzchLhzsW,;WERcesInW qt.'oL.Rtrul;e
doTsW,Wk;Rri@stW aHAHHFndZPpqar.tridgeLinZpe.LtYer.W,:jbye
```

The text preceding the code is something like:

> TeX is a macro language and the meaning of existing commands can be changed on
>   the fly, and also new commands can be dened on the fly [Knu84]. As perhaps the most
>   extreme example of this is David Carlisle's xii.tex TeX code, which is obtainable as http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/xii/xii.tex:

Now my question is, how this so-called extreme example of macro could be simplified to be readable to the beginner TeX/LaTeX users?

I have run the code through TeX and I was really surprised to see the *result*!

One more basic question I do have:

Could all `TeX` commands be used from any `LaTeX` file?

**EDIT**

With the [**answer**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105813/13670) from [**hendrik-vogt**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1235/hendrik-vogt) and the [**related answer**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2295/13670) from [**joseph-wright**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright), I was trying to understand the obfuscated code.

TeXifying the code after adding `\traceall` at the beginning gives perhaps useful  information, but still quite stumbling blocks to me is something like:

```
A71->~`7113\def 
71<-L
{\catcode}
{\def}
```

That seems to me something like [**BF**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck). Not very well, but still I am getting some hints what is going on behind the scene. Can someone help me what does the previous block of code means?

Comment: Hi Cylian, the whole point of that macro is to **not** be readable!  The simplified version would simply be to type the resulting text.

Comment: I am pretty sure David would say that it is already simplified as much as can be. :-)

Comment: @ScottH.: But, I like to on which basis these `entire string` _was written_? Is this code somehow like `Java Bytecodes` that only could be interpreted by the compiler?

Comment: We were asked about another such _document_ very early on in the life of the site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2272.

Comment: I'm very hurt that people don't find my code readable:( Joseph has already given one link, and this came up a day or two ago and there are some links to other sites where this is described http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104248/what-is-the-most-bizarre-thing-you-have-seen-done-with-tex/104263#comment227814_104263

Comment: "As perhaps the most extreme example of this is David Carlisle's xii.tex TeX code, which is obtainable as ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/contrib/xii.tex:" That link appears to be broken.

Comment: @FaheemMitha link updated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### The short answer

There are actually three levels of obfuscation in that code: Firstly, some clever recursive macros are used to compress the text to just a few lines. Secondly, some kind of [substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher) and [transposition ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher) are implemented by rather straightforward macros like `\defR#1#2#3{#3#2#1}` (where `R` is an active character). The third level is the use of category codes to avoid intellegible TeX-specific characters like `{`, `}`, `#` and `\`.

### Some more explanations

I saw this TeX file more that 10 years ago and thought *Eh?* So I tried to take it apart step by step. On the way I learned a lot about TeX's macro language, and also about category codes. To begin with, I'll only post the very first steps I took. (I still have the files on my computer, and this one is named `hae.1`, "hae" being German and meaning "eh?")

```
\let~\catcode  ~`76  ~`A13  ~`F1  ~`j00  ~`P2
\defA#1{~`#113\def}
ALL{
}
A''{w}      A;;{}    AZZ{LaL}    A//#1{#1i}   AHH{L}
Azz{en}     ASS{th}; A$${ev}     A@@{f}
ARR#1#2#3{#3#2#1};
ADD{Rgni}   AWW#1{}  ATT{ve}     A**{stRsam}  AGG{Rruo}
Aqq#1.#2.{#1#2#1}                AYY#1#2{#2#1#1}
A??{i*Lm}   A&&#1\fi{\fi#1}      AVV{\bigskipR}WG
AUU#1#2#3#4 #5,#6{\par#1#2#3#5D\ifx:#6\else&U#6\fi}L
AKK#1#2{#1l#2#1}
AXX#1{VLnOSeL#1SLRyadR@oL RrhC?yLRurtK{eL}{ov}gaTLtReRomL;}
ABB#1 #2,#3:{\if.#3.\else B#3:\fiX{#1}U#1 #2,#3:}Ws;
AMM#1{#1di}  AJJ{Rdri}  AQQ{RsreL}  AII#1{o#1d}  A!!{Rgie}
Bt'el@ lTLqdrYmu.Q.,Ke;vz vzLqpip.Q.,tz;
;Lql.IrsZ.eap,qn.i. i.eLlMaesLdRcna,;!;h htLqm.MRasZ.ilk,%
s$;z zLqs'.ansZ.Ymi,/sx ;LYegseZRyal,@i;@ TLRlogdLrDsW,@;G
LcYlaDLbJsW,SWXJW ree @rzchLhzsW,;WERcesInW qt.'oL.Rtrul;e
doTsW,Wk;Rri@stW aHAHH{ndZ}pqar.tridgeLinZpe.LtYer.W,:\bye
```

You see, I replaced  `F` with `{` and `P` with `}` throughout. Why? `` ~`F1 `` gives the character `F` category code 1 (since the active character `~` is `\let` to `\catcode`), and TeX understands such characters as opening braces. In the same way, `P` is given category code 2 by `` ~`P2 ``, so it acts as a closing brace.

The next thing is to understand `` ~`76 `` and `` ~`j00 ``. The first makes `7` behave like the macro parameter character `#` (category code 6), and the second makes `j` behave like the control sequence character `\` (category code 0), so I've replaced `7` with `#` and `j` with `\` throughout. This enhances readability quite a bit already. Moreover, I added some white space and line breaks, which helps some more.

The key point now is to understand what `A` does. This is an "active character" (category code 13) due to `` ~`A13 ``, so it behaves like a control sequence. So what does the definition `` \defA#1{~`#113\def} `` mean? `A` takes one argument `#1`. Then `~` acts as `\catcode`, so `A` gives it's argument category code 13, and then it issues an additional `\def`.

So how does this fit with the output of `\tracingall` you got? The first line

```
A71->~`7113\def
```

says the following: To the left of `->` you see that the active character `A` takes one argument `#1` (recall that `7` acts as `#`); to the right of `->` you see the corresponding expansion. Now the second line

```
71<-L
```

says that `#1` should be substituted with `L`, so that the expansion is `` ~`L13\def ``. Now `~` was `\let` to `\catcode`, so the category code assignment `` \catcode`L13 `` is performed next (making `L` an active character); then the `\def` is executed. This is what you see in the next two lines:

```
{\catcode}
{\def}
```

(Unfortunately `\tracingall` doesn't say anything specific about the execution of `\catcode` and `\def`.)

Let's look at the usage `A''{w}`. This expands to `` \catcode`'13\def'{w} ``, so `'` is made an active character, and it's given a definition, namely that `'` should expand to `w` (one of the transposition ciphers)! Just one more example: `A??{i*Lm}` makes `?` active and gives it the definition `i*Lm`, which in turn expands to `istRsam m` since `*` expands to `stRsam` and `L` to a space. The final result is `istmas m` since `R` acts as a transposition cipher, as mentioned in the very beginning. And now we're able to understand the little piece `RrhC?y` in the code – it expands to `Christmas my`!

### A challenge

If you remove all the cipher and catcode business, you just have some recursive macros that represent the text rather efficiently. Can anyone do it with less than 479 characters?

```
\let~\def~\U#1,#2:{\par#1ing \if.#2.\else\U#2:\fi}~\,{\def\,{and
}}~\;#1~#2 #3,#4:{\if.#4.\else\;#4:\fi\bigskip On the #1#2th day of
Christmas my true love gave to me\U#1#3,#4:}~~#1 {}\;twel~f ve drummers
drumm,eleven~ \ pipers pip,ten~ \ lords a leap,nin~ e ladies danc,eigh~
t maids a milk,seven~ \ swans a swimm,six~ \ geese a lay,fi~f ve gold
rings~,four~ \ calling birds~,th~ird\ ~ ree french hens~,~second\ ~ two
turtle doves~,~first\ ~ \,a partridge in a pear tree.~,:\bye
```

Comment: I really appreciate the approach.

Comment: Inspired by your helpful start, I started to decipher it myself, but somewhere around `\def B` it becomes too painful to follow. I salute you for your efforts!

Comment: @morbusg: `B` just does the recursion `:-)`

Comment: Unputdownable! Wish I could vote it more than once! One question, could you tell me a book from where I could acquire some knowledge to learn this kind of tricks. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: In the code at the end, I think, in the definition of `\U`, one should transform `\U#2:\fi` to `\fi\U#2:`, so that we don't get too many levels of nested `\if`s, as in the original `xii.tex`, or one doesn't have to do so?

Answer (score 16):

I think actually it is as simple as it can be already. It has two `\` which is, I admit, rather complicated. I did try to simplify it so that it only had one, or even better no, backslash but I don't think that is possible.

Comment: By two backslashes, do you mean the `\catcode\`j=00`? I.e., why the second zero?

Comment: @morbusg: No, the code starts with ``\let~\``, so the density of ``\`` is rather high at the beginning `:-)` And the double `0` is just to get full justification of the code.

Comment: @Hendrik: Ah, OK, thanks for the explanation. Haha this has to be sickest piece of code I have ever seen! I got over the `A` definition, but after that, I just keep shifting between looking at the input and looking at the output, and I can't help my mind exploding over and over again! Brain... hurts...

Comment: @HendrikVogt you don't want to know how long I spent trying to avoid that density:-)

Comment: Can you make the `\let`, `\catcode`, `def` and `bye` more obscure?

Comment: @Karl'sstudents let and catcode no as I say I tried to avoid having any backslash but 2 was the lowest I could get (without slipping a back door into the latex format which was tempting) bye I could get rid of but only by having csname endcsname somewhere in the code and I was trying to avoid too many control names even with j

Comment: I just see two points where the code could be less obvious: In the last line, there's a strong smell of partridge (but I always thought that you left this thread of hope intentionally), and the `bye` could be hidden somewhere in the middle of the code, where also the `bigskip` is hiding so well that @Karl didn't even mention it `:-)`

Comment: @HendrikVogt `partridge` is because I had to make a quick fix (the first version I posted to c.t.t I'd obfuscated in a spelling error (to pear as I recall, and I had to quickly rejig it and I couldn't obfuscate partridge any more without adding a new line:-) `\bye` is `\outer` in plain so a bit harder to hide.

Comment: @David: Ah OK, if you don't have time, then fixing a spelling error is quite a challenge here. (By the way, [I felt compelled](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9006) to further condense your code.) Concerning `\bye`: I thought of something along the lines of `\let~\bye Hello world~`.

Comment: @HendrikVogt when the code was published in TUGBoat Barbara Beeton claimed that it should be lords-a-leaping, I told her she was the editor, she was welcome to add the `-` where needed:-)

Answer (score 10):

Here is one simplification I found from https://bitbucket.org/ambrevar/xii.tex/overview by Pierre Neidhardt:

```
\def\endverse{}

\def\verse#1 #2,#3:{\if.#3.\par #2{}\else\par#2\verse#3:\fi}

\def\day#1{\bigskip On the #1 day of Christmas my true love gave to me}

\def\gen#1 #2,#3:{\if.#3.\else \gen#3:\fi\day{#1}\verse#1 #2,#3:}


\gen
twelfth twelve drummers drumming,%
eleven eleven pipers piping,%
tenth ten lords a leaping,%
ninth nine ladies dancing,%
eighth eight maids a milk,%
seventh seven swans a swimm,%
sixth six geese a lay,%
fifth five gold rings,%
fourth fourr calling birds,%
third three french hens,% 
second two turtle doves,%
first \endverse\def\endverse{and }a partridge in a pear tree.,:

\bye
```

Comment: After reading it seems like no-puzzle at all. Nice resource. But, I also find another one https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=fr&fromgroups=#!topic/fr.comp.text.tex/tkyaRYXQWnQ, mentioned by the creator of the puzzle.