# Where to install a .tex file in TDS?

Tags: fun, tds, xii

This is a follow-on from [How to get latest version of xii.tex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406913). From the comments to that question (many thanks) it appears the the two remarkable files from David Carlisle `xii.tex` and `xii-lat.tex` are located on my computer via `tlmgr` in `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/plain`. Where is the best place to put them so that I can simply do `pdftex xii-lat` (or `xii`) and get a PDF output?

I should know an answer but, being a GOM, just in case...

Comment: if you put it in whatever local tds tree you have /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/plain/xii/xii.tex for example or if you just want the pdf `texdoc xii` works.

Comment: @David Carlisle `texdoc xii` and `texdoc xii-lat` just result in a `README.txt`  file.

Comment: @oh so it does and texdoc xii.pdf gives Bruno's reversi file:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `xii-lat.tex` would be found, if it were installed below `TDS:tex/plain/`. But the [TDS specification](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/tds/tds.pdf) (or [CTAN version](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/tds/tds.pdf) without links) writes:

> 3.1 Macros
>
> TeX macro files shall be stored in separate directories, segregated by
>   TeX format and package name (we use "format" in its traditional TeX
>   sense to mean a usefully `\dump`-able package):
>
> ```
> texmf/tex/⟨format⟩/⟨package⟩/
> ```
>
> ⟨format⟩ is a format name (examples: `amstex`, `latex`, `plain`,
>   `texinfo`).

The directory tree below `TDS:tex/` contains macro files like LaTeX classes, packages or plain macro files. It should be small, to avoid loading/parsing large hierarchies, when compiling a TeX document.

A better place is below `TDS:doc/`. From the specification:

> 3.7 Documentation
>
> Most packages come with some form of documentation: user manuals,
>   example files, programming guides, etc. In addition, many independent
>   files not part of any macro or other package have been created to
>   describe various aspects of the TeX system. The TDS specifies that
>   these additional documentation files shall be stored in a structure
>   that parallels to some extent the fonts and tex directories, as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> texmf/doc/⟨category⟩/...
> ```

It is also the place for example files, and test files, source code for the documentation, ...

Therefore, the current place below `TDS:doc/plain` looks correct for me.

A place for discussing is AFAIK the [TeX live mailing list](https://www.tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live).

Comment: I will try on the mailing list. I feel that `xii` and friends could be put under a category called perhaps `fun` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

In theory you could compile them if they were below the `tex` level, e.g. in `tex/plain`: You can e.g. try in some temp folder `pdflatex article.cls`, pdflatex will then start to compile article.cls (naturally this will gives errors).

But imho this is not a sane system (in more complicated document you will run into problems with inputs) and you should better copy example files that you want to compile in your document folder and compile there.

Comment: I like your answer but Heiko gave a more detailed one. I just feel that `xii` and friends are in a special category, but maybe I'm being picky.

Comment: Well the files from @DavidCarlisle are certainly in a special category. But nevertheless they are not *ressources*.